# Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers

Tags: javascript, serialization, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

Is there a commonly accepted technique for efficiently converting JavaScript strings to [ArrayBuffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) and vice-versa? Specifically, I'd like to be able to write the contents of an ArrayBuffer to `localStorage` and then read it back.

Comment: I don't have any experience in this, but judging from the API documentation (http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/) if you build an `Int8Array` `ArrayBufferView` it might be possible to simply use the bracket notation to copy chars `string[i] = buffer[i]` and vice versa.

Comment: @FK82, that looks like a reasonable approach (using `Uint16Array`s for JS's 16-bit characters), but JavaScript strings are immutable so you can't assign directly to a character position. I would still need to copy `String.fromCharCode(x)` of each value in the `Uint16Array` to a normal `Array` and then call `.join()` on the `Array`.

Comment: @kpozin: True, didn't really think that through.

Comment: @kpozin It turns out that most modern JS engines have optimized string concatenation to the point where it's cheaper to just use `string += String.fromCharCode(buffer[i]);`. It does seem odd that there wouldn't be built-in methods for converting between strings and typed arrays. They had to know something like this would come up.

Comment: arrayBuffer.toString() is working well for me.

Comment: @citizen conn - I don't know what browser you're using, but on Chrome arrayBuffer.toString() just gives "[object ArrayBuffer]". Not very helpful.

Comment: @download, [Citation needed](http://xkcd.com/285). Indeed, that isn't quite logically possible since the concatenation is done dynamically (as opposed to pre-compiled). Running `+=` in a loop will give youj some serious bottlenecks.

Comment: async version: `str = await new Response(str).arrayBuffer()`

Comment: @mrec Convert the ArrayBuffer to a TypedArray first.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

**Update 2016** - five years on there are now new methods in the specs (see support below) to convert between strings and typed arrays using proper encoding.

### TextEncoder

The [`TextEncoder` represents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder):

> The `TextEncoder` interface represents an encoder for a specific method,
>   that is a specific character encoding, like `utf-8`, <del>`iso-8859-2`, `koi8`,
>   `cp1261`, `gbk`, ...</del> An encoder takes a stream of code points as input and
>   emits a stream of bytes.

**Change note since the above was written:** (ibid.)

> Note: Firefox, Chrome and Opera used to have support for encoding
>   types other than utf-8 (such as utf-16, iso-8859-2, koi8, cp1261, and
>   gbk). As of Firefox 48 [...], Chrome 54 [...] and Opera 41, no
>   other encoding types are available other than utf-8, in order to match
>   the spec.*

*) [Updated specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/encoding/#dom-textencoder) (W3) and [here](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-textencoder) (whatwg).

After creating an instance of the `TextEncoder` it will take a string and encode it using a given encoding parameter:

```js
if (!("TextEncoder" in window)) 
  alert("Sorry, this browser does not support TextEncoder...");

var enc = new TextEncoder(); // always utf-8
console.log(enc.encode("This is a string converted to a Uint8Array"));
```

You then of course use the `.buffer` parameter on the resulting `Uint8Array` to convert the underlaying `ArrayBuffer` to a different view if needed.

Just make sure that the characters in the string adhere to the encoding schema, for example, if you use characters outside the UTF-8 range in the example they will be encoded to two bytes instead of one.

For general use you would use UTF-16 encoding for things like `localStorage`.

### TextDecoder

Likewise, the opposite process [uses the `TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder):

> The `TextDecoder` interface represents a decoder for a specific method,
>   that is a specific character encoding, like `utf-8`, `iso-8859-2`, `koi8`,
>   `cp1261`, `gbk`, ... A decoder takes a stream of bytes as input and emits
>   a stream of code points.

All available decoding types can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder#Parameters).

```js
if (!("TextDecoder" in window))
  alert("Sorry, this browser does not support TextDecoder...");

var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
var arr = new Uint8Array([84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,85,105,110,116,
                          56,65,114,114,97,121,32,99,111,110,118,101,114,116,
                          101,100,32,116,111,32,97,32,115,116,114,105,110,103]);
console.log(enc.decode(arr));
```

### The MDN StringView library

An alternative to these is to use the [`StringView` library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/StringView) (licensed as lgpl-3.0) which goal is:

> - to create a C-like interface for strings (i.e., an array of character codes — an ArrayBufferView in JavaScript) based upon the
>     JavaScript ArrayBuffer interface
> - to create a highly extensible library that anyone can extend by adding methods to the object StringView.prototype
> - to create a collection of methods for such string-like objects (since now: stringViews) which work strictly on arrays of numbers
>     rather than on creating new immutable JavaScript strings
> - to work with Unicode encodings other than JavaScript's default UTF-16 DOMStrings

giving much more flexibility. However, it would require us to link to or embed this library while `TextEncoder`/`TextDecoder` is being built-in in modern browsers.

## Support

As of July/2018:

[`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) (Experimental, On Standard Track)

```
 Chrome    | Edge      | Firefox   | IE        | Opera     | Safari
 ----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
     38    |     ?     |    19°    |     -     |     25    |     -

 Chrome/A  | Edge/mob  | Firefox/A | Opera/A   |Safari/iOS | Webview/A
 ----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
     38    |     ?     |    19°    |     ?     |     -     |     38

°) 18: Firefox 18 implemented an earlier and slightly different version
of the specification.

WEB WORKER SUPPORT:

Experimental, On Standard Track

 Chrome    | Edge      | Firefox   | IE        | Opera     | Safari
 ----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
     38    |     ?     |     20    |     -     |     25    |     -

 Chrome/A  | Edge/mob  | Firefox/A | Opera/A   |Safari/iOS | Webview/A
 ----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
     38    |     ?     |     20    |     ?     |     -     |     38

Data from MDN - `npm i -g mdncomp` by epistemex
```

Comment: No support for TextDecoder from IE & Edge: https://caniuse.com/#search=TextDecoder

Comment: According to MS it's in development: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/encodingstandard/

Comment: No support for Safari Mobile(ios) at 2018-04-18: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder

Comment: One-liner: `var encoder = 'TextEncoder' in window ? new TextEncoder() : {encode: function(str){return Uint8Array.from(str, function(c){return c.codePointAt(0);});}};` so you can just `var array = encoder.encode('hello');`

Comment: The thing with `TextEncoder` is that if you have binary data in a string (like, image), you don't want to use `TextEncoder` (apparently). Characters with code points greater than 127 produce two bytes. Why do I have binary data in a string? `cy.fixture(NAME, 'binary')` (`cypress`) produces a string.

Comment: For IE support, you can use the [FastestSmallestTextEncoderDecoder](https://github.com/anonyco/FastestSmallestTextEncoderDecoder) polyfill, as recommended by the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder).

Comment: You should wrap `new TextDecoder("encoding")` in a try/catch because you might have support for TextDecoder but not the character encoding you want to use.

Comment: What does `ibid` mean?

Comment: @mikemaccana [ibid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibid.): "commonly used ... to refer to the source cited in the preceding note or list item."

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer. The question asked for "converting ArrayBuffer to string, and store in localStorage", and what this answer suggests is using TextDecoder to decode the binary data into string. However, we don't know whether the ArrayBuffer was created *from* a string in the first place (likely not). When it's not, from my test, it doesn't work as intended at all. (when converted from binary to string then back, it becomes completely different)

Answer (score 202):

Although Dennis and gengkev solutions of using Blob/FileReader work, I wouldn't suggest taking that approach. It is an async approach to a simple problem, and it is much slower than a direct solution. I've made a post in html5rocks with a simpler and (much faster) solution: 
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String

And the solution is:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

The [Encoding API helps solving the string conversion](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/08/Easier-ArrayBuffer---String-conversion-with-the-Encoding-API) problem. Check out the response from [Jeff Posnik](http://www.html5rocks.com/profiles/#jeffposnick) on Html5Rocks.com to the above original article.

Excerpt:

> *The Encoding API makes it simple to translate between raw bytes and native JavaScript strings, regardless of which of the many standard encodings you need to work with.*

```
<pre id="results"></pre>

<script>
  if ('TextDecoder' in window) {
    // The local files to be fetched, mapped to the encoding that they're using.
    var filesToEncoding = {
      'utf8.bin': 'utf-8',
      'utf16le.bin': 'utf-16le',
      'macintosh.bin': 'macintosh'
    };

    Object.keys(filesToEncoding).forEach(function(file) {
      fetchAndDecode(file, filesToEncoding[file]);
    });
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#results').textContent = 'Your browser does not support the Encoding API.'
  }

  // Use XHR to fetch `file` and interpret its contents as being encoded with `encoding`.
  function fetchAndDecode(file, encoding) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file);
    // Using 'arraybuffer' as the responseType ensures that the raw data is returned,
    // rather than letting XMLHttpRequest decode the data first.
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        // The decode() method takes a DataView as a parameter, which is a wrapper on top of the ArrayBuffer.
        var dataView = new DataView(this.response);
        // The TextDecoder interface is documented at http://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-textdecoder
        var decoder = new TextDecoder(encoding);
        var decodedString = decoder.decode(dataView);
        // Add the decoded file's text to the <pre> element on the page.
        document.querySelector('#results').textContent += decodedString + '\n';
      } else {
        console.error('Error while requesting', file, this);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I wrote a detailed answer on your html5rocks article (as soon it will be approved).

Comment: Will any arbitrary byte array survive a round trip with this method? Are there any circumstances under which we may lose data if a value in the array (e.g. `0xD800`) happens to correspond to an invalid code point? The ultimate goal here is to have a reliable way to persist the contents of `ArrayBuffer`s.

Comment: kpozin: in theory, it should. To make sure it does - at least in Chrome - you can run this code in the JavaScript console and make sure it doesn't throw an exception: `for (var b=0x0000; b<=0xffff; b++) {abv[0]=b; if (new Uint16Array(str2ab(ab2str(ab)))[0]!==b) { throw "invalid conversion";} }`

Comment: @kpozin, one more thing: if you can change your implementation from localstorage to, for example, indexeddb, do it. Localstorage has several performance/concurrency problems that could get you in trouble under heavy usage - see [this html5rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/)

Comment: Unfortunately my comment on html5rocks is not approved yet. Therefore a short answer here. I still think, this isn't the right way, because you miss plenty of characters, especially because most pages are in UTF-8 encoding today. On one side, for more special characters (let's say Asian), the charCodeAt function returns a 4-Byte value, so they will be chopped. On the other side, simple English characters will grow the ArrayBuffer twice (you're using 2 Byte for every 1-Byte character). Imagine sending an English text over a WebSocket, it will need twice time (not good in real time environment).

Comment: @Dennis, I think this answer fits my use case. My main goal is to be able to persist the contents of ArrayBuffers that contain arbitrary binary data. I'm not (in this case) looking for an efficient conversion from strings containing actual text content.

Comment: @Dennis, JavaScript chars are 2-byte values.

Comment: Three examples:

(1) `This is a cool text!` 20 Byte in UTF8 -- 40 Byte in Unicode.
(2) `ÄÖÜ` 6 Bytes in UTF8 -- 6 Bytes in Unicode.
(3) `☐☑☒` 9 Bytes in UTF8 -- 6 Bytes in Unicode.

If you want to store the string as UTF8-file (via Blob and File Writer API), you cannot use this 2 methods, because the ArrayBuffer will be in Unicode and not in UTF8.

Comment: I get an error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Dennis - JS strings use UCS2, not UTF8 (or even UTF16) - meaning charCodeAt() always returns values 0 -> 65535.  Any UTF-8 code point that requires 4 bytes ends will be represented with surrogate pairs (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF ) - i.e. two separate 16-bit UCS2 values.

Comment: @jacob - I believe the error is because there's a limit on the length of the array that can be passed to the apply() method.  E.g. `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(new ArrayBuffer(246300))).length` works for me in Chrome, but if you use 246301 instead, I get your RangeError exception

Comment: For even better performance, use TextDecoder/TextEncoder where available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder

Comment: @broofa: charCodeAt() indeed always returns values less than 65536, but that does not mean that characters encoded by surrogates get 2 positions in the string: rather, it means we lose information when calling charCodeAt(), as it only returns the lower 16 bits of the real character code.

Comment: @broofa: Sorry, a correction to my previous comments: it seems you're perfectly right; as unfortunate as it may be, JS strings are in fact not unicode strings :-/

Comment: When using ab2str: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: +1 for TextDecoder/TextEncoder: the html5rocks article now mentions it as a native, and probably faster, API... (in retrospect i'm not sure how i even came up with my original answer)

Comment: If the solution doesn't work, or you get an unexpected set of characters, then try using one of the [following TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#TypedArray_objects) objects instead. In my case, the `buf` was a `Uint8Array`, so setting the return value of `ab2str` to `return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));` did the trick.

Comment: Here's a version that handles all codepoints that JavaScript can handle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17192845/309483

Comment: Typed arrays are very slow input for `String.fromCharCode.apply`. It's much faster to append one character at a time in a loop - which also isn't limited by the call stack.

Comment: @mangini,how it to be done if I have 32 bit array,please help.

Comment: Good idea is to use Uint8Array, not 16. There may be problems with size if it's not dividable by 2.

Comment: @bryc If I'm not mistaken, building a string by repeated appending is a horrible O(n^2) situation due to strings being immutable

Comment: @Steven Lu I am not familiar with that - could you give an example of a 'horrible O(n^2) situation'? In my use-case, I was only parsing a 12-character string. I forget what exactly I was doing, but `Uint8Array` didn't play well with `fromCharCode.apply` performance-wise.

Comment: Well I certainly am not saying that `fromCharCode.apply` is any kind of a good idea either. Basically the point is that if your string is large, `string = string + 'a'` takes time linear in the length of string (because, not being mutable, the time taken to append any character cannot be amortized because a whole new string instance must be allocated). If strings are built via the repeated appending of single characters, this makes the entire string building process take quadratic time (with a linear number of allocations as opposed to a more palatable logarithmic number of them)

Comment: This answer definitely should be removed, because it gives trash instead of data.

Comment: @Dennis: Javascript strings are more like an abomination mix of UCS-2 and UTF-16. Regardless of that, UCS-2, UTF-8, and UTF-16 are **all** _implementations_ of unicode. [JavaScript’s internal character encoding: UCS-2 or UTF-16?](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding)

Comment: One-liner for `str2ab`:
`function str2ab(str) {
        return (new Uint16Array(str.length)).map((_,i) => str.charCodeAt(i));
    }`

Comment: I get this error in Typescript for the ab2String function: Argument of type 'Uint16Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'Uint16Array' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': pop, push, concat, shift, and 3 more.

Answer (score 116):

You can use `TextEncoder` and `TextDecoder` from the [Encoding standard](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/), which is polyfilled by the [stringencoding library](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding), to convert string to and from ArrayBuffers:

```js
var uint8array = new TextEncoder().encode(string);
var string = new TextDecoder(encoding).decode(uint8array);
```

Comment: By the way, this is available in Firefox by default: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder.decode

Comment: Thumbs up for new APIs which are much better than weird workarounds!

Comment: This won't work with all types of characters out there.

Comment: `npm install text-encoding`, `var textEncoding = require('text-encoding');  var TextDecoder = textEncoding.TextDecoder;`. No thanks.

Comment: grumble ... if I have an existing arraybuffer I want to write a string into I guess I have to take the uint8array and copy it a 2nd time??

Comment: I used this but was not getting a 1:1 (65 character string to 65 length array buffer). This works: `new Uint8Array(str.split('').map((ea) => { return ea.charCodeAt(0) }));` This was specifically for getting a private key into a Uint8Array for webpush.

Comment: The fastest solution so far: https://jsbench.me/b6klaaxgwq/1

Answer (score 48):

Blob is much slower than `String.fromCharCode(null,array);`

but that fails if the array buffer gets too big. The best solution I have found is to use `String.fromCharCode(null,array);` and split it up into operations that won't blow the stack, but are faster than a single char at a time.

The best solution for large array buffer is:

```
function arrayBufferToString(buffer){

    var bufView = new Uint16Array(buffer);
    var length = bufView.length;
    var result = '';
    var addition = Math.pow(2,16)-1;

    for(var i = 0;i<length;i+=addition){

        if(i + addition > length){
            addition = length - i;
        }
        result += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bufView.subarray(i,i+addition));
    }

    return result;

}
```

I found this to be about 20 times faster than using blob. It also works for large strings of over 100mb.

Comment: We should go with this solution. As this solves one more use case than the accepted one

Comment: I get: "Uncaught INVALID: json decode: this isn't json!"

Answer (score 32):

In case you have binary data in a string (obtained from `nodejs` + `readFile(..., 'binary')`, or `cypress` + `cy.fixture(..., 'binary')`, etc), you can't use `TextEncoder`. It supports only `utf8`. Bytes with values `>= 128` are each turned into 2 bytes.

ES2015:

```
a = Uint8Array.from(s, x => x.charCodeAt(0))
```

Uint8Array(33) [2, 134, 140, 186, 82, 70, 108, 182, 233, 40, 143, 247, 29, 76, 245, 206, 29, 87, 48, 160, 78, 225, 242, 56, 236, 201, 80, 80, 152, 118, 92, 144, 48

```
s = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, a)
```

"ºRFl¶é(÷LõÎW0 Náò8ìÉPPv\0"

Comment: Thank you for the simplest solution!

Comment: Any way to make the `fromCharCode` TypeScript ready? It complains that `a` is not a `number[]`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: That's the only answer that worked for me when using pdf.js. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Based on the answer of gengkev, I created functions for both ways, because [BlobBuilder](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#idl-def-BlobBuilder) can handle String and ArrayBuffer:

```
function string2ArrayBuffer(string, callback) {
    var bb = new BlobBuilder();
    bb.append(string);
    var f = new FileReader();
    f.onload = function(e) {
        callback(e.target.result);
    }
    f.readAsArrayBuffer(bb.getBlob());
}
```

and

```
function arrayBuffer2String(buf, callback) {
    var bb = new BlobBuilder();
    bb.append(buf);
    var f = new FileReader();
    f.onload = function(e) {
        callback(e.target.result)
    }
    f.readAsText(bb.getBlob());
}
```

A simple test:

```
string2ArrayBuffer("abc",
    function (buf) {
        var uInt8 = new Uint8Array(buf);
        console.log(uInt8); // Returns `Uint8Array { 0=97, 1=98, 2=99}`

        arrayBuffer2String(buf, 
            function (string) {
                console.log(string); // returns "abc"
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: In arrayBuffer2String(), did you mean to call callback(...) instead of console.log()? Otherwise the callback argument goes unused.

Comment: This looks like the way to go -- thanks genkev and Dennis. Seems kind of silly that there's no synchronous way to accomplish this, but what can you do...

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. Therefore the FileReader is asynchronous for two reasons: (1) it will not block the execution of other JavaScript while loading a (huge) file (imagine a more complex application) and (2) it will not block the UI/Browser (common problem with long executing JS code). Plenty of APIs are asynchronous. Even in XMLHttpRequest 2 the synchronous is removed.

Comment: I was really hoping this would work for me, but the conversion from string to ArrayBuffer is not working reliably.  I am making an ArrayBuffer with 256 values, and can turn that into a string with length 256.  But then if I try to convert that back to an ArrayBuffer - depending on the contents of my initial ArrayBuffer - I'm getting out 376 elements.  If you want to try to reproduce my problem, I'm treating my ArrayBuffer as a 16x16 grid in a Uint8Array, with values calculated as `a[y * w + x] = (x + y) / 2 * 16;`  I've tried `getBlob("x")`, with many different mimetypes - no luck.

Comment: BlobBuilder is deprecated in newer browsers. Change `new BlobBuilder(); bb.append(buf);` to `new Blob([buf])`, cast the ArrayBuffer in the second function to a UintArray via `new UintArray(buf)` (or whatever's appropriate for the underlying data type), and then get rid of the `getBlob()` calls. Finally, for cleanliness, rename bb to blob because it's not a BlobBuilder anymore.

Comment: @sowbug do you have a reference for me?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/BlobBuilder#Notes_on_BlobBuilder_deprecation, and current tip-of-tree builds of Chrome give a log warning about deprecation. Also http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them

Comment: I stumbled over the article on html5rocks by myself some days ago. It's in the W3C spec since 17th April: "The BlobBuilder interface is deprecated in favor of the new constructible Blob. However, at this time implementations generally support BlobBuilder and not constructible Blob." http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#idl-def-BlobBuilder -- Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

## Just

```
const buffer = thisReturnsBuffers();

const blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});

blob.text().then(text => console.log(text));
```

Or

```
const stringVal = "string here";

const blob = new Blob([stringVal], {type: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});

blob.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => console.log(buffer));
```

Why are you all making this so complicated?

Comment: I think this won't work in the case of string containing binary data? I think you'll need to put it in a uint8array first

Comment: Ah, in the browser that would have already been stripped. Strings can't hold arbitrary bytes there. Is it different on Node?

Comment: I'm not an expert but an example in the browser is the USVString you can receive from a blob. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text

Comment: If you're starting from a blob you probably shouldn't convert it to a string to then make a buffer, since blob.arrayBuffer is more direct.

Answer (score 20):

### All the following is about getting binary strings from array buffers

I'd recommend not to use

```
var binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
```

because it

1. **crashes** on big buffers (somebody wrote about "magic" size of 246300 but I got `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error on 120000 bytes buffer (Chrome 29))
2. it has **really poor performance** (see below)

If you exactly need synchronous solution use something like

```
var
  binaryString = '',
  bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer),
  length = bytes.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  binaryString += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
}
```

it is as slow as the previous one but works correctly. It seems that at the moment of writing this there is no quite fast synchronous solution for that problem (all libraries mentioned in this topic uses the same approach for their synchronous features).

But what I really recommend is using `Blob` + `FileReader` approach

```
function readBinaryStringFromArrayBuffer (arrayBuffer, onSuccess, onFail) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    onSuccess(event.target.result);
  };
  reader.onerror = function (event) {
    onFail(event.target.error);
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(new Blob([ arrayBuffer ],
    { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));
}
```

the only disadvantage (not for all) is that it is **asynchronous**. And it is about **8-10 times faster** then previous solutions! (Some details: synchronous solution on my environment took 950-1050 ms for 2.4Mb buffer but solution with FileReader had times about 100-120 ms for the same amount of data. And I have tested *both* synchronous solutions on 100Kb buffer and they have taken almost the same time, so loop is not much slower the using 'apply'.)

BTW here: [How to convert ArrayBuffer to and from String](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String) author compares two approaches like me and get completely opposite results ([his test code is here](http://jsperf.com/arraybuffer-string-conversion/4)) Why so different results? Probably because of his test string that is 1Kb long (he called it "veryLongStr"). My buffer was a really big JPEG image of size 2.4Mb.

Comment: Thanks for this async file reader solution. On 50MB chunks of a 717MB video file, it decreases the time to convert the buffer to a string by between 67% and 96%. That's huge. From many seconds to some hundreds of milliseconds

Answer (score 16):

(**Update** Please see the 2nd half of this answer, where I have (hopefully) provided a more complete solution.)

I also ran into this issue, the following works for me in FF 6 (for one direction):

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer( 10 );
var view = new Uint8Array( buf );
view[ 3 ] = 4;
alert(Array.prototype.slice.call(view).join(""));
```

Unfortunately, of course, you end up with ASCII text representations of the values in the array, rather than characters. It still (should be) much more efficient than a loop, though.
eg. For the example above, the result is `0004000000`, rather than several null chars & a chr(4).

**Edit:**

After looking on **MDC** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array), you may create an `ArrayBuffer` from an `Array` as follows:

```
var arr = new Array(23);
// New Uint8Array() converts the Array elements
//  to Uint8s & creates a new ArrayBuffer
//  to store them in & a corresponding view.
//  To get at the generated ArrayBuffer,
//  you can then access it as below, with the .buffer property
var buf = new Uint8Array( arr ).buffer;
```

To answer your original question, this allows you to convert `ArrayBuffer` <-> `String` as follows:

```
var buf, view, str;
buf = new ArrayBuffer( 256 );
view = new Uint8Array( buf );

view[ 0 ] = 7; // Some dummy values
view[ 2 ] = 4;

// ...

// 1. Buffer -> String (as byte array "list")
str = bufferToString(buf);
alert(str); // Alerts "7,0,4,..."

// 1. String (as byte array) -> Buffer    
buf = stringToBuffer(str);
alert(new Uint8Array( buf )[ 2 ]); // Alerts "4"

// Converts any ArrayBuffer to a string
//  (a comma-separated list of ASCII ordinals,
//  NOT a string of characters from the ordinals
//  in the buffer elements)
function bufferToString( buf ) {
    var view = new Uint8Array( buf );
    return Array.prototype.join.call(view, ",");
}
// Converts a comma-separated ASCII ordinal string list
//  back to an ArrayBuffer (see note for bufferToString())
function stringToBuffer( str ) {
    var arr = str.split(",")
      , view = new Uint8Array( arr );
    return view.buffer;
}
```

For convenience, here is a `function` for converting a raw Unicode `String` to an `ArrayBuffer` (will only work with ASCII/one-byte characters)

```
function rawStringToBuffer( str ) {
    var idx, len = str.length, arr = new Array( len );
    for ( idx = 0 ; idx < len ; ++idx ) {
        arr[ idx ] = str.charCodeAt(idx) & 0xFF;
    }
    // You may create an ArrayBuffer from a standard array (of values) as follows:
    return new Uint8Array( arr ).buffer;
}

// Alerts "97"
alert(new Uint8Array( rawStringToBuffer("abc") )[ 0 ]);
```

The above allow you to go from `ArrayBuffer` -> `String` & back to `ArrayBuffer` again, where the string may be stored in eg. `.localStorage` :)

Hope this helps,

Dan

Comment: I don't think this is an efficient method (in terms of time or space), and this is a very unusual way to store binary data.

Comment: What about using base64 encoding?

Answer (score 16):

Unlike the solutions here, I needed to convert to/from UTF-8 data. For this purpose, I coded the following two functions, using the (un)escape/(en)decodeURIComponent trick. They're pretty wasteful of memory, allocating 9 times the length of the encoded utf8-string, though those should be recovered by gc. Just don't use them for 100mb text.

```
function utf8AbFromStr(str) {
    var strUtf8 = unescape(encodeURIComponent(str));
    var ab = new Uint8Array(strUtf8.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < strUtf8.length; i++) {
        ab[i] = strUtf8.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return ab;
}

function strFromUtf8Ab(ab) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, ab)));
}
```

Checking that it works:

```
strFromUtf8Ab(utf8AbFromStr('latinкирилицаαβγδεζηあいうえお'))
-> "latinкирилицаαβγδεζηあいうえお"
```

Comment: A widely supported solution with a decent preformance: https://jsbench.me/b6klaaxgwq/1

Answer (score 11):

For node.js and also for browsers using https://github.com/feross/buffer

```
function ab2str(buf: Uint8Array) {
  return Buffer.from(buf).toString('base64');
}
function str2ab(str: string) {
  return new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(str, 'base64'))
}
```

Note: Solutions here didn't work for me. I need to support node.js and browsers and just serialize UInt8Array to a string. I could serialize it as a number[] but that occupies unnecessary space. With that solution I don't need to worry about encodings since it's base64. Just in case other people struggle with the same problem... My two cents

Answer (score 7):

I found I had problems with this approach, basically because I was trying to write the output to a file and it was non encoded properly. Since JS seems to use UCS-2 encoding ([source](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding), [source](http://www.2ality.com/2013/09/javascript-unicode.html)), we need to stretch this solution a step further, here's my enhanced solution that works to me.

I had no difficulties with generic text, but when it was down to Arab or Korean, the output file didn't have all the chars but instead was showing error characters

**File output:**

`","10k unit":"",Follow:"Õ©íüY‹","Follow %{screen_name}":"%{screen_name}U“’Õ©íü",Tweet:"Ä¤üÈ","Tweet %{hashtag}":"%{hashtag} ’Ä¤üÈY‹","Tweet to %{name}":"%{name}U“xÄ¤üÈY‹"},ko:{"%{followers_count} followers":"%{followers_count}…X \Ì","100K+":"100Ì tÁ","10k unit":"Ì è",Follow:"\°","Follow %{screen_name}":"%{screen_name} Ø \°X0",K:"œ",M:"1Ì",Tweet:"¸","Tweet %{hashtag}":"%{hashtag}`

**Original:**

`","10k unit":"万",Follow:"フォローする","Follow %{screen_name}":"%{screen_name}さんをフォロー",Tweet:"ツイート","Tweet %{hashtag}":"%{hashtag} をツイートする","Tweet to %{name}":"%{name}さんへツイートする"},ko:{"%{followers_count} followers":"%{followers_count}명의 팔로워","100K+":"100만 이상","10k unit":"만 단위",Follow:"팔로우","Follow %{screen_name}":"%{screen_name} 님 팔로우하기",K:"천",M:"백만",Tweet:"트윗","Tweet %{hashtag}":"%{hashtag}`

I took the information from [dennis' solution](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String) and [this post](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.ca/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html) I found.

Here's my code:

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}

 function ab2str(buf) {
   var s = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
   return decode_utf8(decode_utf8(s))
 }

function str2ab(str) {
   var s = encode_utf8(str)
   var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length); 
   var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
   for (var i=0, strLen=s.length; i<strLen; i++) {
     bufView[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   return bufView;
 }
```

This allows me to save the content to a file without encoding problems.

How it works: 
It basically takes the single 8-byte chunks composing a UTF-8 character and saves them as single characters (therefore an UTF-8 character built in this way, could be composed by 1-4 of these characters).
UTF-8 encodes characters in a format that variates from 1 to 4 bytes in length. What we do here is encoding the sting in an URI component and then take this component and translate it in the corresponding 8 byte character. In this way we don't lose the information given by UTF8 characters that are more than 1 byte long.

Answer (score 6):

if you used huge array example `arr.length=1000000`
you can this code to avoid stack callback problems

```
function ab2str(buf) {
var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
var unis =""
for (var i = 0; i < bufView.length; i++) {
    unis=unis+String.fromCharCode(bufView[i]);
}
return unis
}
```

reverse function 
[mangini answer  from top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058858/5301860)

```
function str2ab(str) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
    var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following is a working **Typescript** implementation:

```
bufferToString(buffer: ArrayBuffer): string {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.from(new Uint16Array(buffer)));
}

stringToBuffer(value: string): ArrayBuffer {
    let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(value.length * 2); // 2 bytes per char
    let view = new Uint16Array(buffer);
    for (let i = 0, length = value.length; i < length; i++) {
        view[i] = value.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

I've used this for numerous operations while working with **crypto.subtle**.

Comment: This was my favorite approach, however, how could you do a check if "data" is Buffer?

Comment: If the data is a string. If it is UTF16 or a smaller encoding, it can be turned into an ArrayBuffer with this function. It doesn't mean that buffer will be useful for other things, such as changing into an image. If you want to know that, you'll have to look at what the image format is and sniff it. Most file types have metadata at the start.

Answer (score 5):

Well, here's a somewhat convoluted way of doing the same thing:

```
var string = "Blah blah blah", output;
var bb = new (window.BlobBuilder||window.WebKitBlobBuilder||window.MozBlobBuilder)();
bb.append(string);
var f = new FileReader();
f.onload = function(e) {
  // do whatever
  output = e.target.result;
}
f.readAsArrayBuffer(bb.getBlob());
```

**Edit:** BlobBuilder has long been deprecated in favor of the Blob constructor, which did not exist when I first wrote this post. Here's an updated version. (And yes, this has always been a very silly way to do the conversion, but it was just for fun!)

```
var string = "Blah blah blah", output;
var f = new FileReader();
f.onload = function(e) {
  // do whatever
  output = e.target.result;
};
f.readAsArrayBuffer(new Blob([string]));
```

Answer (score 5):

Recently I also need to do this for one of my project so did a well research and got a result from Google's Developer community which states this in a simple manner:

**For ArrayBuffer to String**

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
// Here Uint16 can be different like Uinit8/Uint32 depending upon your buffer value type.
```

**For String to ArrayBuffer**

```
function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
//Same here also for the Uint16Array.
```

For more in detail reference you can refer [this blog by Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String).

Comment: This method inserted 'NUL' characters in my text… The solution that worked for me is https://stackoverflow.com/a/45722000/1134119

Answer (score 4):

```
  stringToArrayBuffer(byteString) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      byteArray[i] = byteString.codePointAt(i);
    }
    return byteArray;
  }
  arrayBufferToString(buffer) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var byteString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
      byteString += String.fromCodePoint(byteArray[i]);
    }
    return byteString;
  }
```

Comment: this code is buggy if string contains unicode characters. example: `arrayBufferToString(stringToArrayBuffer(''))==='44'`

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have an arrayBuffer binaryStr:

```
let text = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(binaryStr));
```

and then you assign the text to the state.

Answer (score 3):

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/StringView
(a C-like interface for strings based upon the JavaScript ArrayBuffer interface)

Comment: That code is under the GPLv3.  I think it's pretty unprofessional of Mozilla to even blend that code with their standards-compliant documentation.

Answer (score 3):

After playing with mangini's solution for converting from `ArrayBuffer` to `String` - `ab2str` (which is the most elegant and useful one I have found - thanks!), I had some issues when handling large arrays. More specefivally, calling `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));` throws an error:

`arguments array passed to Function.prototype.apply is too large`.

In order to solve it (bypass) I have decided to handle the input `ArrayBuffer` in chunks. So the modified solution is:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
   var str = "";
   var ab = new Uint16Array(buf);
   var abLen = ab.length;
   var CHUNK_SIZE = Math.pow(2, 16);
   var offset, len, subab;
   for (offset = 0; offset < abLen; offset += CHUNK_SIZE) {
      len = Math.min(CHUNK_SIZE, abLen-offset);
      subab = ab.subarray(offset, offset+len);
      str += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, subab);
   }
   return str;
}
```

The chunk size is set to `2^16` because this was the size I have found to work in my development  landscape. Setting a higher value caused the same error to reoccur. It can be altered by setting the `CHUNK_SIZE` variable to a different value. It is important to have an even number.

Note on performance - I did not make any performance tests for this solution. However, since it is based on the previous solution, and can handle large arrays, I see no reason why not to use it.

Comment: you can use [typedarray.subarray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray) to get a chunk at specified position and size, this is what i do to read headers off binary formats in js

Answer (score 3):

I used this and works for me.

```
function arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}



function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string =  window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
const encstr = (`TextEncoder` in window) ? new TextEncoder().encode(str) : Uint8Array.from(str, c => c.codePointAt(0));
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this worked well.

```js
  static async hash(message) {
    const data = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data)
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer))
    const hashHex = hashArray.map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')
    return hashHex
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The "native" binary string that atob() returns is a 1-byte-per-character Array.

So we shouldn't store 2 byte into a character.

```
var arrayBufferToString = function(buffer) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
}

var stringToArrayBuffer = function(str) {
  return (new Uint8Array([].map.call(str,function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0)}))).buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**`ArrayBuffer` -> `Buffer` -> `String(Base64)`**

Change `ArrayBuffer` to `Buffer` and then to `String`.

```
Buffer.from(arrBuffer).toString("base64");
```

Comment: Any way to convert back?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yes, see cancerbero's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57834448/14007952. Surprised how elegant this gets amidst all the hairy solutions here!

Comment: This is node-only solution, does not work in browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Use splat unpacking instead of loops:

```js
arrbuf = new Uint8Array([104, 101, 108, 108, 111])
text = String.fromCharCode(...arrbuf)
console.log(text)
```

For substrings `arrbuf.slice()` can be employed.

Comment: It won't work for non ascii charcters (utf-8 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

## I'd recommend NOT using deprecated APIs like BlobBuilder

BlobBuilder has long been deprecated by the Blob object. Compare the code in Dennis' answer — where BlobBuilder is used — with the code below:

```
function arrayBufferGen(str, cb) {

  var b = new Blob([str]);
  var f = new FileReader();

  f.onload = function(e) {
    cb(e.target.result);
  }

  f.readAsArrayBuffer(b);

}
```

Note how much cleaner and less bloated this is compared to the deprecated method... Yeah, this is definitely something to consider here.

Comment: I mean, yes, but that Blob constructor wasn't really usable back in 2012 ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var decoder = new TextDecoder ();
var string = decoder.decode (arrayBuffer);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/decode

Answer (score 0):

From emscripten:

```js
function stringToUTF8Array(str, outU8Array, outIdx, maxBytesToWrite) {
  if (!(maxBytesToWrite > 0)) return 0;
  var startIdx = outIdx;
  var endIdx = outIdx + maxBytesToWrite - 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    var u = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (u >= 55296 && u <= 57343) {
      var u1 = str.charCodeAt(++i);
      u = 65536 + ((u & 1023) << 10) | u1 & 1023
    }
    if (u <= 127) {
      if (outIdx >= endIdx) break;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = u
    } else if (u <= 2047) {
      if (outIdx + 1 >= endIdx) break;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = 192 | u >> 6;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = 128 | u & 63
    } else if (u <= 65535) {
      if (outIdx + 2 >= endIdx) break;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = 224 | u >> 12;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = 128 | u >> 6 & 63;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = 128 | u & 63
    } else {
      if (outIdx + 3 >= endIdx) break;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = 240 | u >> 18;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = 128 | u >> 12 & 63;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = 128 | u >> 6 & 63;
      outU8Array[outIdx++] = 128 | u & 63
    }
  }
  outU8Array[outIdx] = 0;
  return outIdx - startIdx
}
```

Use like:

```js
stringToUTF8Array('abs', new Uint8Array(3), 0, 4);
```