# Trying To Parse Bytes With Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using an old API that returns bytes :(

When I do this API request, I am getting the following response

```
\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x03SPY\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01=\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\x00\x00\x01\\a\ufffdb\x00\ufffd\ufffd
```

What I am looking to pull out of this mess is something along the lines of .1083.  Does anyone have any guesses on how I might be able to do this via javacript?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240408/reading-bytes-from-a-javascript-string

Comment: you can also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994712/how-do-i-read-binary-data-to-a-byte-array-in-javascript