# Convert nodejs' Buffer to browsers' javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I'm converting my code from Node.js to browsers' javascript, but I have a problem with the Buffers in node.js. How can I use them in Javascript?

Here's an example:

```
new Buffer("foo", encoding='utf8')
<Buffer 66 6f 6f>
```

I need to transform [66, 6f, 6f] in javascript to "foo" and vice-versa. How can I do that?
NOTE: this must be done without Node.js.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I discovered a library I use for web3 included Buffer as a function
You can include as CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereumjs/browser-builds/dist/ethereumjs-tx/ethereumjs-tx-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use the function as this:

```
ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from(valueToConvert,'hex');
```

Answer (score 15):

With https://github.com/substack/node-browserify you can work with buffers in the Browser by using: https://github.com/toots/buffer-browserify. However: this can be very slow in the browser: For faster access use https://github.com/chrisdickinson/bops

Comment: These days this lives here: https://github.com/feross/buffer

Comment: Now (2022), https://github.com/StableLib/stablelib/tree/master/packages might bring a solution as well, in particular utf-8 and hex modules

Answer (score 12):

There is no direct support for Buffer in browser-based JavaScript, and I am not aware of any compatibility library that implements the Buffer API (yet).

The equivalent functionality in the browser is provided by TypedArrays.  You can learn about them here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

When porting a Node Buffer-based implementation to browser-based JavaScript, I found these answers helpful:

- [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)
- [Javascript - Converting between Unicode string and ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006600/javascript-converting-between-unicode-string-and-arraybuffer)

Comment: There is now a [browser `Buffer` compatibility library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12486045/201952).

Answer (score -8):

To convert back to the string, use the buffer's toString method with a supplied encoding.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffers.html#buffer.toString

```
var buffer = new Buffer("foo", "utf8");
var str = buffer.toString("utf8");
str === "foo";
```

Comment: No, no, I need an alternative to Buffer(). Thank you anyway :) I need to run it in browsers' javascript.

Comment: Note that if the `Buffer` ends with an incomplete UTF-8 sequence that `toString()` is not sufficient, you will end up with a broken last character. (This can happen if you are using Buffer to read in a stream with unknown text content.) In this case the solution is to use instead [`StringDecoder`](http://nodejs.org/api/string_decoder.html)

Comment: Bumping +1, this was useful info for me in Node.