# Sharing binary buffer between Node.js server and Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

There is an issue of how to share buffers between node.js and the browser containing binary data. I'm pretty happy with [Socket.io](http://socket.io) as a transport layer but the issue is that there is no porting of the [Buffer class](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) for the browser. Not something I can find anyways

I've also came across [binary.js](http://binaryjs.com/) and I was wondering if there is a good way to combine them having the socket.io as the transport layer and the Binary.js as the data medium. I also saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880571/convert-nodejs-buffer-to-browsers-javascript), which is kind of on topic but doesn't really resolve the issue.

I know socket.io added binary support but I haven't found any documentation on the topic.

**Update:**

It seems that binary.js will not be the solution. The basic requirement that I want is to share the same capabilities that Buffer has in node with the browser.

My needs consist of two things:

1. Handle the buffer in the same manner in both Server and Browser.
2. support Binary data.

I will probably use Array Buffer.

Edit: 
Since node.js run over V8 you can use ArrayBuffer. It seems as if the issue is solved. Yet, from what I know, node people decided that it's a good idea to create a buffer module and manage it in the C bindings they created (from a talk given by Ryan Dahl). I think this has to do with how buffering is done over the network. This means ArrayBuffer is still not a good data medium to share between server  and browser.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the problem is. What functionality are you exactly interested in that does not exist in the browser?

Comment: My needs consist of two things: 
1. Handle the buffer in the same manner in both Server and Browser.
2. Support Binary data.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: The problem is not that functionality isn't available in the browser, it's that the functionality that is available in the browser (typed arrays) isn't available in `node.js`. He doesn't want to have to write all his code twice.

Comment: Hi @DavidSchwartz thanks for promoting this question. I've added some details to clarify the Array Buffer issue.

Comment: @qballer: Is ArrayBuffer available in the most prevalent versions of IE and `node.js`? If so, that sounds like a solution.

Comment: Nope, ArrayBuffer will only come out with IE10. There is still a performance issue with buffering a data structure from the V8. That is why node.js run the buffer module outside of V8

Comment: Interesting topic, I'm curious about using BinaryJS with Socket.io for backwards compatibility with http sockets.  I don't have enough background knowledge about the two at this moment to say much, but it would definitely be interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[browser-buffer](https://github.com/arextar/browser-buffer) emulates Node's `Buffer` API in the browser.

It's backed by a [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array), so [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=typedarrays) is sketchy.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I'm looking for, the thing is, it's still very unstable.

Comment: Yeah, there's very little activity in the project; it looks like it's someone's experimental code.  I'd use it as a good starting point -- you're going to have to fork and improve the code.

Comment: These days this lives here: https://github.com/feross/buffer

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's built in strings use wide characters internally. So they can easily store a value from 0 to 255 in each character position. This is a JavaScript language feature, so it should work the same in a browser or in `node.js`.

You can use `charCodeAt` to extract the value of a particular position in a string and `fromCharCode` to create a character (that you can add to a string) with a value from 0 to 255.

You can use the various string functions to manipulate data in this form. You can create constants using JavaScript string constants like this `"\x00\x12\x34\x56"`.