# Buffer + writeUInt32LE from NodeJS to Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, arraybuffer

So I have this function, comming from a NodeJS script:

```
function WearToFloat(value)
{
    buf = new Buffer(4);
    buf.writeUInt32LE(+value, 0);
    return buf.readFloatLE(0).toString();
}
```

and I need to translate this in pure Javascript that can be read by any web browser.

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no knowledge in NodeJS nor buffers in JS, and can't figure out with docs.

The aim of this function is to convert a value that looks like `1054356424` into a float number from 0 to 1 (in this case, 0.4222700595855713)

Any clue?

Edit: Seems that the same kind of question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880571/convert-nodejs-buffer-to-browsers-javascript) but only using a library, and I don't want to load a full library just for that, there must be a simple way to convert this NodeJS function into a Javascript one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert nodejs' Buffer to browsers' javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880571/convert-nodejs-buffer-to-browsers-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found!

```
function WearToFloat(value)
{
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var dataview = new DataView(buffer);
    dataView.setUint32(0,value);
    return dataView.getFloat32(0);
}
```

Comment: You might need to set `setUInt32` 3rd parameter to true in order to switch endianness behaviour to "Little endian". Doc says, by default Big endian is assumed. Same goes for getFloat32 with its 2nd parameter. `;)`