# How to use Nodejs's Buffer in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, buffer

How can i use/call [Nodejs's Buffer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_buffers.htm) in Angularjs ? i spent many hours in google but i can not find the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In nodeJs, i wrote some code like: 
var buffer = new Buffer(9);
buffer.writeUInt8(3, 0);               
buffer.writeUInt32LE(0x00040000, 1); 
buffer.writeUInt32LE(10, 5);   

how i can do the same thing in Angulars JS ? Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Buffer is a native Node.js API. It does not exist in standard JS

Comment: @borislemke: Thanks for your reply. i found this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer, can i import and use it in my Angular app ? if yes, how can i do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880571/convert-nodejs-buffer-to-browsers-javascript

Comment: I'm not familiar with that module, but if it works as it describes itself, you might as well give it a try

Comment: i'm always searching the solution. i appreciate any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The idea is using ArrayBuffer, DataView of Javascript to make the same thing as Buffer of NodeJS.

For example, in NodeJS, i wrote something:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(9); 
buffer.writeUInt8(3, 0); 
buffer.writeUInt32LE(0x00040000, 1);
```

The corresponding code in Javascript like the following:

```
 var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(9);
 var dataview = new DataView(buffer);
 dataview.setUint8(0, 3);            
 dataview.setUint32(1, parseInt('0x00040000'), true);
```

Hope this helps for anyone have the same problem.

Comment: Hi [@V-Q-A-NGUYEN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599865/v-q-a-nguyen) , do you know how can I use this method to convert this type of buffer usage?`Buffer.from('some text', 'utf8')`