# Javascript - get data out of ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, arraybuffer

I've got a drag and drop script that uses `readAsArrayBuffer()`.  The length of the buffer is perfect, but I can't seem to figure out how to pull the data out of the buffer.

Apparently I've got to make a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/DataView) or an [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array) or something, then iterate through its `byteLength`...help!

*EDIT*
Pertinent code (there's not much of it):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    // do something with e.target.result, which is an ArrayBuffer
} 
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(someFileHandle);
```

Comment: We might need a bit more code for this. Are you using a `FileReader`? Or what is providing `readAsArrayBuffer()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might change based on your answer to my comment, but if I assume that you are using a `FileReader` somewhere, you need to read it's `result` attribute in the `loaded` callback that you need to provide:

```
function loaded(evt) {  
  var datastring = evt.target.result;

  // do something here
}

reader.onload = loaded; // where reader is a FileReader, FileReaderSync
```

**Update:** Ah, I see. Well then your best course of action is to follow to this duplicate:

[Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

**Update2:** Note that you could probably use `readAsText()` then, but I don't know if you're at liberty to do this.

Comment: Yep, got that far thanks, but the `.result` property is of type `ArrayBuffer`.  How can I extract the data from that?

Comment: @Steve: what do you mean by "extracting"? What do you want to do **exactly**?

Comment: Say the file contains a string: `foobarbaz`.  I want something like `alert(datastring)` to alert `foobarbaz`.  Right now, the alert says `[object ArrayBuffer]`.

Comment: @Steve: updated my answer, pointing you to another thread that provides what you need.

Comment: Thanks haylem. That's the one.  Om.