# How do i encrypt and decrypt Uint8Array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, cryptojs

I want encryption and decryption of a Uint8Array for that i have downloaded CryptoJS library from this [link](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).

I have tested aes cipher algorithm on a dummy string its working fine.

Now i want it to implement it on Uint8Array. This array is holding a video file data.

Since the encryption and decryption works on a string, i have to convert it to a string for that i have referenced this question posted on the stackoverflow [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

Code for encryption is :

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uInt8Array), "test");
```

But when i ran the code following error is coming:

```
 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How do i make it working?

Answer (score 2):

That error is due the `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uInt8Array)` part, CryptoJS is never called.

Note that full syntax of `fromCharCode` is `String.fromCharCode(n1, n2, ..., nX)`, so all elements of the given buffer must be moved to the stack in order to `apply` the function.

You must be using a very big buffer, a video file you said, so that must be the reason you got a stackoverflow error.

Try to use a `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray' instead, as described here:

http://groups.google.com/group/crypto-js/browse_thread/thread/4ce6fddad709954d?pli=1

Comment: Thanks juan for replying. Yeh this buffer contains video file data (v11.webm 10.5 MB). How can i apply encryption/decryption?

Comment: @PankajKhurana I'm not a CryptoJS user, just pointing you in the right direction. Anyway, a quick look at library documentation reveals that _"the cipher algorithms accept either strings or instances of CryptoJS.lib.WordArray"_. I think you could follow from there, I would do it.

Comment: i had a look at it but could not find any relevant info. can you please suggest me some other library which can get the job done?