# How fast are Web Worker's messages?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I wondered if transmission to or from a web worker can be a bottleneck.
Should we post message just as we trigger any kind of events, or should we take care and try to limit as much as possible the communication between the two ?

Let's have an example. If I have a huge array that is dynamically constructed (e.g. an array of contact points coming from `mousemove` or `touchmove` for a gesture recogniser), is it more efficient to transfer the data iteratively – i.e. send each element as soon as we receive it and let the worker store them on its side – or is it better to store them on the main thread and send all the data at once at the end, in particular when one cannot use a transferable object?

Comment: I just realised I actually didn't really answer the original question - how fast. radubogdan is right. I'd maybe correct him to *pretty damn fast*. What is slow is the overhead for single transfer, as I could verify with the performance testing script I added to my answer.

Comment: To be honest, I added the last point at the end of the last sentence after your post. So this my fault not your's. Sorry about that.

Comment: @QuentinRoy The benchmark I added to my answer last time I edited it shows that difference between transfer/copy is negligible. But what really counts is the buffering - try sending 100Mb in 1, 10 or 100 chunks, you will see how drastically the speed drops.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well you can buffer the data in `Uint16Array`<sup>**1**</sup>. You can then do a little trick and **move** the data instead of copying. See **[this demo on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Passing_data_by_transferring_ownership_%28transferable_objects%29)** for an introduction.

<sup>**1:** should be enough for screens smaller than 16x16 meters at pixel density 0.25 pixels per milimeter, which I believe is most screens on the world</sup>

## 1. How fast?

First to your question, let's test the web workers speed.

I created this test snippet that attempts to measure actual speed of workers. But **attempts** is important here. Truly I figured out that only reliable way of measuring the time will *affect* the time, much like what we experience in modern physic theories.

What the code definitely can tell us is that buffering is a good idea. First textbox sets the **total** amount of data to be sent. Second sets the number of samples to divide the data in. You'll soon find out that overhead with samples is notable. Checkbox allows you to chose whether to transfer data or not. This starts to matter with bigger amount of data, just as anticipated.

Please forgive the messy code, I can't force myself to *behave* when writing exciting test snippets.
I created this tjes

```js
function WorkerFN() {
  console.log('WORKER: Worker ready for data.');
  // Amount of data expected
  var expectedData = 0;
  // Amount of data received
  var receivedData = 0;
  self.onmessage = function(e) {
      var type = e.data.type;
      if(type=="data") {
          receivedData+=e.data.data.byteLength;
          self.postMessage({type: "timeResponse", timeStart: e.data.time, timeHere: performance.now(), bytes: e.data.data.byteLength, all:expectedData<=receivedData});
      }
      else if(type=="expectData") {
          if(receivedData>0 && receivedData<expectedData) {
              console.warn("There is transmission in progress already!");  
          }
          console.log("Expecting ", e.data.bytes, " bytes of data.");
          expectedData = e.data.bytes;
          receivedData = 0;
      }
  }
}

var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["("+WorkerFN.toString()+")()"], {type: 'text/javascript'})));

/** SPEED CALCULATION IN THIS BLOCK **/
var results = {
  transfered: 0,
  timeIntegral: 0 //Total time between sending data and receiving confirmation
}
// I just love getters and setters. They are so irresistably confusing :)
// ... little bit like women. You think you're just changing a value and whoops - a function triggers
Object.defineProperty(results, "speed", {get: function() {
  if(this.timeIntegral>0)
    return (this.transfered/this.timeIntegral)*1000;
  else
    return this.transfered==0?0:Infinity;
}
});
// Worker sends times he received the messages with data, we can compare them with sent time
worker.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  var type = e.data.type;
  if(type=="timeResponse") {
    results.transfered+=e.data.bytes;
    results.timeIntegral+=e.data.timeHere-e.data.timeStart;
    // Display finish message if allowed
    if(e.data.all) {
        status("Done. Approx speed: "+humanFileSize(Math.round(results.speed/100)/10, true)+"/s"); 
        addRecentResult();
    }
  }
});

/** GUI CRAP HERE **/
// Firefox caches disabled values after page reload, which makes testing a pain
$(".disableIfWorking").attr("disabled", false);
$("#start_measure").click(startMeasure);
$("#bytes").on("input", function() {
  $("#readableBytes").text(humanFileSize(this.value, true));
});
$("#readableBytes").text(humanFileSize($("#bytes").val()*1||0, true));

function addRecentResult() {
  var bytes = $("#bytes").val()*1;
  var chunks = $("#chunks").val()*1;
  var bpch = Math.ceil(bytes/chunks);
  var string = '<tr><td class="transfer '+($("#transfer")[0].checked)+'">    </td><td class="speed">'+humanFileSize(results.speed, true)+'/s</td><td class="bytes">'+humanFileSize(bytes, true)+'</td><td class="bpch">'+humanFileSize(bpch, true)+'</td><td class="time">'+results.timeIntegral+'</td></tr>';
  if($("#results td.transfer").length==0)
    $("#results").append(string);
  else
    $(string).insertBefore($($("#results td.transfer")[0].parentNode));
}
function status(text, className) {
  $("#status_value").text(text);
  if(typeof className=="string")
    $("#status")[0].className = className;
  else
    $("#status")[0].className = "";
}
window.addEventListener("error",function(e) {
  status(e.message, "error");
  // Enable buttons again
  $(".disableIfWorking").attr("disabled", false);
});
function startMeasure() {
  if(Number.isNaN(1*$("#bytes").val()) || Number.isNaN(1*$("#chunks").val()))
    return status("Fill the damn fields!", "error");
  $(".disableIfWorking").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  DataFabricator(1*$("#bytes").val(), 1*$("#chunks").val(), sendData);
}

/** SENDING DATA HERE **/
function sendData(dataArray, bytes, bytesPerChunk, transfer, currentOffset) {
  // Initialisation before async recursion
  if(typeof currentOffset!="number") {
    worker.postMessage({type:"expectData", bytes: bytesPerChunk*dataArray.length});
    // Reset results
    results.timeIntegral = 0;
    results.transfered = 0;
    results.finish = false;
    setTimeout(sendData, 500, dataArray, bytes, bytesPerChunk, $("#transfer")[0].checked, 0);
  }
  else {
    var param1 = {
         type:"data",
         time: performance.now(),
         data: dataArray[currentOffset]
    };
    // I decided it's optimal to write code twice and use if
    if(transfer)
      worker.postMessage(param1, [dataArray[currentOffset]]);
    else 
      worker.postMessage(param1);
    // Allow GC
    dataArray[currentOffset] = undefined;
    // Increment offset
    currentOffset++; 
    // Continue or re-enable controls
    if(currentOffset<dataArray.length) {
    // Update status
      status("Sending data... "+Math.round((currentOffset/dataArray.length)*100)+"% at "+humanFileSize(Math.round(results.speed/100)/10, true)+"/s");
      setTimeout(sendData, 100, dataArray, bytes, bytesPerChunk, transfer, currentOffset);
    }
    else {
      //status("Done. Approx speed: "+humanFileSize(Math.round(results.speed/100)/10, true)+"/s");
      $(".disableIfWorking").attr("disabled", false);
      results.finish = true;
    }
  }
}
/** CREATING DATA HERE **/
function DataFabricator(bytes, chunks, callback) {
  var loop;

  var args = [
      chunks, // How many chunks to create
      bytes,  // How many bytes to transfer total
      Math.ceil(bytes/chunks), // How many bytes per chunk, byt min 1 byte per chunk
      0,      // Which offset of current chunk are we filling
      [],     // Array of existing chunks
      null,   // Currently created chunk
  ];
  // Yeah this is so damn evil it randomly turns bytes in your memory to 666
  //                                                     ... yes I said BYTES
  (loop=function(chunks, bytes, bytesPerChunk, chunkOffset, chunkArray, currentChunk) {
    var time = performance.now();
    // Runs for max 40ms
    while(performance.now()-time<40) {
      if(currentChunk==null) {
        currentChunk = new Uint8Array(bytesPerChunk);
        chunkOffset = 0;
        chunkArray.push(currentChunk.buffer);
      }
      if(chunkOffset>=currentChunk.length) {
        // This means the array is full
        if(chunkArray.length>=chunks)
          break;
        else {
          currentChunk = null;
          // Back to the top
          continue;
        }
      }
      currentChunk[chunkOffset] = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
      // No need to change every value in array
      chunkOffset+=Math.floor(bytesPerChunk/5)||1;
    }
    // Calculate progress in bytes
    var progress = (chunkArray.length-1)*bytesPerChunk+chunkOffset;
    status("Generating data - "+(Math.round((progress/(bytesPerChunk*chunks))*1000)/10)+"%");
    
    if(chunkArray.length<chunks || chunkOffset<currentChunk.length) {
      // NOTE: MODIFYING arguments IS PERFORMANCE KILLER!
      Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, loop, 5);
      setTimeout.apply(null, arguments);
    }
    else {
      callback(chunkArray, bytes, bytesPerChunk);
      Array.splice.call(arguments, 0);
    }
  }).apply(this, args);
}
/** HELPER FUNCTIONS **/
// Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14919494/607407
function humanFileSize(bytes, si) {
    var thresh = si ? 1000 : 1024;
    if(Math.abs(bytes) < thresh) {
        return bytes + ' B';
    }
    var units = si
        ? ['kB','MB','GB','TB','PB','EB','ZB','YB']
        : ['KiB','MiB','GiB','TiB','PiB','EiB','ZiB','YiB'];
    var u = -1;
    do {
        bytes /= thresh;
        ++u;
    } while(Math.abs(bytes) >= thresh && u < units.length - 1);
    return bytes.toFixed(1)+' '+units[u];
}
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}
#start_measure {
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color:orange;
}
button#start_measure[disabled] {
   border: 1px solid #333;
   font-style: italic;
   background-color:#AAA;
   width: 100%;
}
.buttontd {
  text-align: center;
}
#status {
  margin-top: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#status.error {
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #FF3214;
}
#status.error div.status_text {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: red;
}
#status_value {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px dotted black;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
div.status_text {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
#results {
  width: 100%
}
#results th {
  padding: 3px;
  border-top:1px solid black;
}
#results td, #results th {
  border-right: 1px dotted black;
}
#results td::first-child, #results th::first-child {
  border-left: 1px dotted black;
}
#results td.transfer.false {
  background-color: red;
}
#results td.transfer.true {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>Bytes to send total: </td><td><input class="disableIfWorking" id="bytes" type="text" pattern="\d*" placeholder="1024"/></td><td id="readableBytes"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Divide in chunks: </td><td><input class="disableIfWorking" id="chunks" type="text" pattern="\d*" placeholder="number of chunks"/></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Use transfer: </td><td>    <input class="disableIfWorking" id="transfer" type="checkbox" checked /></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" class="buttontd"><button id="start_measure" class="disableIfWorking">Start measuring speed</button></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

<div id="status"><div class="status_text">Status </div><span id="status_value">idle</span></div>

<h2>Recent results:</h2>
<table id="results" cellpading="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th>transfer</th><th>Speed</th><th>Volume</th><th>Per chunk</th><th>Time (only transfer)</th></tr>

</table>
```

## 2. Buffering

I'll stick to the mouse pointer example, because it's easy to simulate. We'll make a program that calculates mouse pointer path distance using web worker.

What we're gonna do is real, old school buffering. We make a fixed size array (only those allow transferring to workers) and fill it while remembering last point we filled. When we're at the end, we can send the array and create another.

```
// Creating a buffer
this.buffer = new Uint16Array(256);
this.bufferOffset = 0;
```

We can save coordinates easily then, as long as we do not let `bufferOffset` overflow the `buffer`:

```
if(this.bufferOffset>=this.buffer.length)
    this.sendAndResetBuffer();
this.buffer[this.bufferOffset++] = X;
this.buffer[this.bufferOffset++] = Y;
```

## 3. Transfering the data

You've already seen the example on MDN (right...?) so just a quick recapitulation:

```
worker.postMessage(myTypedArray.buffer, [myTypedArray.buffer]);
// The buffer must be empty now!
console.assert(myTypedArray.buffer.byteLength==0)
```

## 4. The buffer pseudo class

Here's what I came with for the buffering and sending data. The class is created with desired max buffer length. It then stores data (pointer locations in this case) and dispatches to the Worker.

```
/** MousePointerBuffer saves mouse locations and when it's buffer is full,
    sends them as array to the web worker.
  * worker - valid worker object ready to accept messages
  * buffer_size - size of the buffer, in BYTES, not numbers or points
**/
function MousePointerBuffer(worker, buffer_size) {
    this.worker = worker;
    if(buffer_size%4!=0)
        throw new Error("MousePointerBuffer requires complement of 4 bytes number, because 1 mouse point is 2 shorts which is 4 bytes!");
    this.buffer_size = buffer_size/2;
    // Make buffer lazy
    this.buffer = null;
    this.bufferOffset = 0;
    // This will print the aproximate time taken to send data + all of the overheads
    worker.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        if(e.data.type=="timer")
            console.log("Approximate time: ", e.data.time-this.lastSentTime);
    }.bind(this));
}
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.makeBuffer = function() {
    if(this.buffer!=null) {
        // Buffer created and not full
        if(this.bufferOffset<this.buffer_size)
            return;
        // Buffer full, send it then re-create
        else
            this.sendBuffer();
    }
    this.buffer = new Uint16Array(this.buffer_size);
    this.bufferOffset = 0;
}
/** Sends current buffer, even if not full. Data is sent as array
    [ArrayBuffer buffer, Number bufferLength] where buffer length means
    occupied bytes. **/
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.sendBuffer = function() {
    this.lastSentTime = performance.now();
    console.log("Sending ",this.buffer.buffer.byteLength," bytes at: ",this.lastSentTime);
    this.worker.postMessage([this.buffer.buffer, this.bufferOffset]
                            , [this.buffer.buffer]  // Comment this line out to see
                                                    // How fast is it without transfer
    );
    // See? Bytes are gone.
    console.log("Bytes in buffer after sending: ",this.buffer.buffer.byteLength);
    this.buffer = null;
    this.bufferOffset = 0;
}
/* Creates event callback for mouse move events. Callback is stored in
   .listener property for later removal **/
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.startRecording = function() {
    // The || expression alows to use cached listener from the past
    this.listener = this.listener||this.recordPointerEvent.bind(this);   
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.listener);
}
/* Can be used to stop any time, doesn't send buffer though! **/
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.stopRecording = function() { 
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.listener);
}
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.recordPointerEvent = function(event) {
    // This is probably not very efficient but makes code shorter
    // Of course 90% time that function call just returns immediatelly
    this.makeBuffer();
    // Save numbers - remember that ++ first returns then increments
    this.buffer[this.bufferOffset++] = event.clientX;
    this.buffer[this.bufferOffset++] = event.clientY;
}
```

## 4. Live example

```js
function WorkerFN() {
  console.log('WORKER: Worker ready for data.');
  // Variable to store mouse pointer path distance
  var dist = 0;
  // Last coordinates from last iteration - filled by first iteration
  var last_x = null,
      last_y = null;
  // Sums pythagorian distances between points
  function calcPath(array, lastPoint) {
      var i=0;
      // If first iteration, first point is the inital one
      if(last_x==null||last_y==null) {
          last_x = array[0];
          last_y = array[1];
          // So first point is already skipped
          i+=2;
      }
      // We're iterating by 2 so redyce final length by 1
      var l=lastPoint-1
      // Now loop trough points and calculate distances
      for(; i<l; i+=2) {
          console.log(dist,last_x, last_y);
          dist+=Math.sqrt((last_x-array[i]) * (last_x-array[i])+
                          (last_y-array[i+1])*(last_y-array[i+1])
          );
          last_x = array[i];
          last_y = array[i+1];
      }
      // Tell the browser about the distance
      self.postMessage({type:"dist", dist: dist});
  }
  self.onmessage = function(e) {
      if(e.data instanceof Array) {
          self.postMessage({type:'timer', time:performance.now()});
          setTimeout(calcPath, 0, new Uint16Array(e.data[0]), e.data[1]);
      }
      else if(e.data.type=="reset") {
          self.postMessage({type:"dist", dist: dist=0});
      }
  }
}

var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["("+WorkerFN.toString()+")()"], {type: 'text/javascript'})));

/** MousePointerBuffer saves mouse locations and when it's buffer is full,
    sends them as array to the web worker.
  * worker - valid worker object ready to accept messages
  * buffer_size - size of the buffer, in BYTES, not numbers or points
**/
function MousePointerBuffer(worker, buffer_size) {
    this.worker = worker;
    if(buffer_size%4!=0)
        throw new Error("MousePointerBuffer requires complement of 4 bytes number, because 1 mouse point is 2 shorts which is 4 bytes!");
    this.buffer_size = buffer_size/2;
    // Make buffer lazy
    this.buffer = null;
    this.bufferOffset = 0;
    // This will print the aproximate time taken to send data + all of the overheads
    worker.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        if(e.data.type=="timer")
            console.log("Approximate time: ", e.data.time-this.lastSentTime);
    }.bind(this));
}
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.makeBuffer = function() {
    if(this.buffer!=null) {
        // Buffer created and not full
        if(this.bufferOffset<this.buffer_size)
            return;
        // Buffer full, send it then re-create
        else
            this.sendBuffer();
    }
    this.buffer = new Uint16Array(this.buffer_size);
    this.bufferOffset = 0;
}
/** Sends current buffer, even if not full. Data is sent as array
    [ArrayBuffer buffer, Number bufferLength] where buffer length means
    occupied bytes. **/
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.sendBuffer = function() {
    this.lastSentTime = performance.now();
    console.log("Sending ",this.buffer.buffer.byteLength," bytes at: ",this.lastSentTime);
    this.worker.postMessage([this.buffer.buffer, this.bufferOffset]
                            , [this.buffer.buffer]  // Comment this line out to see
                                                    // How fast is it without transfer
    );
    // See? Bytes are gone.
    console.log("Bytes in buffer after sending: ",this.buffer.buffer.byteLength);
    this.buffer = null;
    this.bufferOffset = 0;
}
/* Creates event callback for mouse move events. Callback is stored in
   .listener property for later removal **/
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.startRecording = function() {
    // The || expression alows to use cached listener from the past
    this.listener = this.listener||this.recordPointerEvent.bind(this);   
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.listener);
}
/* Can be used to stop any time, doesn't send buffer though! **/
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.stopRecording = function() { 
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.listener);
}
MousePointerBuffer.prototype.recordPointerEvent = function(event) {
    // This is probably not very efficient but makes code shorter
    // Of course 90% time that function call just returns immediatelly
    this.makeBuffer();
    // Save numbers - remember that ++ first returns then increments
    this.buffer[this.bufferOffset++] = event.clientX;
    this.buffer[this.bufferOffset++] = event.clientY;
}
var buffer = new MousePointerBuffer(worker, 400);
buffer.startRecording();
// Cache text node reffernce here
var textNode = document.getElementById("px").childNodes[0];

worker.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    if(e.data.type=="dist") {
        textNode.data=Math.round(e.data.dist);
    }
});
// The reset button
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
      worker.postMessage({type:"reset"});
      buffer.buffer = new Uint16Array(buffer.buffer_size);
      buffer.bufferOffset = 0;
});
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
#px {
    font-family: "Courier new", monospace;
    min-width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
#square {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
Distance traveled: <span id="px">0</span> pixels<br />
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
Try this, if you hve steady hand, you will make it 800px around:
<div id="square">200x200 pixels</div>
This demo is printing into normal browser console, so take a look there.
```

### 4.1 Relevant lines in demo

On line **110** class is initialized, so you can change buffer length:

```
var buffer = new MousePointerBuffer(worker, 400);
```

On line **83**, you can comment out *transfer* command to simulate normal copy operation. It seems to me that the difference is really insignificant in this case:

```
, [this.buffer.buffer]  // Comment this line out to see
                        // How fast is it without transfer
```

Answer (score 4):

They are as fast as the cpu core that's running it. Having that said, communication between processes always incurs some overhead so batching it will probably net you some additional performance. Personally I would probably use a timer to send the mouse location or location history every 25ms.

The question you should ask yourself is: how often do you need the updates? Is 1 update per second enough? 100? 1000? At what point are you just burning cpu cycles for no added value.

Comment: I am not even wondering about the update yet. Let's assume that the processing will only occur at the end for example. Until then, all the sent messages are only about storing data.

Comment: I know for example that if you cannot use a transferrable object, you must at least consider the time to copy all your data which may already be not that negligible.

Comment: So considering that I guess if there is no real transmission time, it is better to send the data iteratively? Maybe you don't even need to buffer it.

Comment: There will always be some transmission time between processes so buffering would still be a good idea. If you really need all data, than just send them with either fixed buffer size or fixed transmission interval.

Comment: @QuentinRoy When reading your question I didn't notice that you can't use a transferable object so I posted an answer that *does* use transferable objects. It's kinda frustrating I spent so much time with it. Are you sure you can't use transferable interface?

Comment: This is a theoretical question actually. I could use a buffer though I would have to transform my data before. I guess it would compensate the time saved during the transfer..