# How to get error message from array buffer

Tags: typescript, vue.js, arraybuffer, vue-resource, extract-error-message

I have the following request to download a file (using `vue-resource`):

```
this.$http.get(fileUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).
    then(
        (response) => {
            let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.headers.get('content-type') });
            let link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let disposition = response.headers.get('content-disposition');
            let matches = /.*filename=(.*);.*/.exec(disposition);
            let filename = (matches != null && matches[1])
                ? matches[1]
                : 'file';
            if (filename.startsWith('"')
                && filename.endsWith('"')) {
                filename = filename.substr(1, filename.length - 2);
            }
            link.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            link.remove();
        },
        (errorResponse) => {
            // TODO: errorResponse doesn't actually have the error message somehow
            console.error(errorResponse);
        });
```

In my back end (C# asp.net core) I am throwing an execption like this:

```
throw new DomainException("ErrorMessage");
```

I can see in the request in devtools that the message `"ErrorMessage"` is definitely being sent back. It's the only thing visible in both the response and preview tabs in chrome.

However, I can't seem to find that message anywhere to show the user.

Normally I would get it from `errorResponse.bodyText`, but this is `undefined` in this case

---

I have tried everything from calling `errorResponse.body`, `errorResponse.bodyText` (everything gives me `undefined`) and even tried reading it with

```
var decodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, errorResponse.body);
var obj = JSON.parse(decodedString);
var message = obj['message'];
```

which just throws more errors:

> myMixin.ts:257 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at VueComponent. (myMixin.ts:257)

Trying the above again but passing in `new Uint8Array(errorResponse.body)` gives me

> myMixin.ts:257 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at VueComponent. (myMixin.ts:257)

---

Removing `, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }`, I can see the error message exists in `errorResponse.bodyText`.

Why is this happening? How can I just get the error message - which clearly does exist as I can see it in the network tab - and just log it on the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution I needed [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String):

```
let message = String.fromCharCode.apply(
    null, 
    new Uint8Array(errorResponse.body));
```

However, because I'm using TypeScript I was getting some kind of annoying message about `errorResponse.body` not being assignable to type `number[]`, so I'm doing it like this:

```
let message = String.fromCharCode.apply(
    null, 
    new Uint8Array(errorResponse.body) as any);
```

Also note that because my response body had an odd number of characters, I had to use `Uint8Array` instead of `Uint16Array`. See [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754486/how-to-convert-arraybuffer-to-string) for details.