# ArrayBuffer and Uinit8Array Values ( Typed Arrays Values )

Tags: javascript, html, encryption

How can i print the values of  [object ArrayBuffer] and [object Uint8Array] .

I have a variable which i on printing gives me the above objects but i am not able to retrieve their values.

```
encryptedBytes = toSupportedArray(e.target.result);
```

where ,

```
console.log("to send for encryption - e.target.result : "+e.target.result);
```

gives me the result :

**to send for encryption - e.target.result : [object ArrayBuffer]**

and

```
console.log("encryptedBytes : "+encryptedBytes);
```

gives me the result :

**encryptedBytes : [object Uint8Array]**

but how can i retrieve the values of the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

Comment: function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
this particular function is giving me the result as - Ấ縬돐벅蝖粫훂岽糴畅ĸਘ룒흟❙샇ꁴ⮅氅ꄤ䷭瓼襳︽Ⅾ�⁐廙�⋦쎢᳒韫ퟙᚲ뇌턻暈曗ﾠ땶爖һ�䒸륳~欶잒ᚹ�䯀噀ᚦ裁

Comment: Already tried that , now what could be the fix for this