# How to return image from $http.get in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I call a service that returns a promise

```
var onComplete = function(data) {
               $scope.myImage = data;           
            };
```

In my service I make a call to get the image by passing url directly to the image itself:

```
   return $http.get("http://someurl.com/someimagepath")
         .then(function(response){          
          return response.data;
         });
```

All the calls are succeeding and the response.data appears to be holding in an image inside:

```
����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 90
��C




��C      

����"�� 
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$
```

although I'm not sure if it actually does because I'm having trouble displaying it. I've tried (inside index.html)

```
 <img ng-src="{{myImage}}"> 
  and
<img ng-src="{{myImage}}.jpeg"> 
  and   
 <img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{myImage}}">
```

Ideas?
Is it possible to return an actual image from $http.get and convert its response back to image (jpeg, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Based on my experiments with trying to inject images into tags in order to reduce HTTP requests for a single-page angular app I was making, no, it isn't possible.

Comment: What's the end goal here?  If you know `http://someurl.com/someimagepath`, why do you need to download it via an `$http.get()` and then inject it into an `src` tag when you can skip the middle man and simply put the path in the `src` tag?

Comment: @Tom - it was just a test to retrieve some data asynchronously and I thought of retrieving an image with it. No real end goal other than learning AngularJS

Comment: Could you check this question, I'm having similar problems : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161442/render-blob-image-with-angular-4

Comment: this answer actually worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/33125433/4631539

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image that's coming back is in [binary encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure), rather than Base64.

Understandably, `<img>` tags don't support sourcing from binary through attributes, so you'll have to look at another solution.

You could try converting the binary encoding to Base64 at the client side using [TypedArrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) together with the [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) function. Then you'd be able to use

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{myImage}}">
```

[This guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) a by Mozilla covers making an XHR request for and image and reading it directly into a [`UInt8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array). It should be a good starting place.

It's written for plain old Javascript, but translating it to Angular should be a good exercise if you are just learning the ropes.

Comment: Thanks, it does look like a binary string. I'll check out the guides!

Comment: @ra170 Could you post the code for this if you managed to solve it?

Comment: @Tometoyou found the solution by googling around **arraybuffer to base64**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers

Comment: Could you check this question, I'm having similar problems : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161442/render-blob-image-with-angular-4

Answer (score 37):

None of the methods seems to be complete, this is a complete solution:

```
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: imageUrl,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var str = _arrayBufferToBase64(response.data);
    console.log(str);
    // str is base64 encoded.
  }, function(response) {
    console.error('error in getting static img.');
  });


  function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
  }
```

Then I am able to use it directly:

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{img}}">
```

The function to convert **arraybuffer** into **base64** is directly taken from [ArrayBuffer to base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string)

Comment: The scenario of this post matches my situation closely.  I like the potential of this solution, but unfortunately does not like the structure or format of the binary data (byte array) that is being passed back via Angular's $http service.  The Uint8Array comes back empty when trying to create the array of bytes.  I'll post my solution once I discern the difference.

Comment: You saved my day..!! Thank you. @paradite can i know how to retreive list of images and display

Comment: Worked!! Somebody give this guy a medal!!. Also to the future readers the `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` in `$http` is important please do not miss it. I was trying to get it done without it but couldn't. Without this the `_arrayBufferToBase64` seems to return empty string.

Answer (score 18):

Just in case anyone needs it.

In my case, I had to send the request through angular's `$http` service, because of various transformers and other fancy stuff we do with it.

So based on the [Mozilla's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) mentioned earlier, I came up with the following solution:

```
let getImageDataURL = (url, imageType = 'image/jpeg') => {
  return $http.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).then((res) => {
    let blob = new Blob([res.data], {type: imageType});
    return (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
  });
};
```

The basic idea is to set the `responseType` property of the underlying XHR request and the convert the binary content to data URL.

Answer (score 1):

By way of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43032560/418819, you can use "blob" as the responseType and very neatly get the data url with a FileReader.

```
$http.get( url, { responseType: "blob" } ).then((result) => {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL( result.data );
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    return e.target.result;
  };
});
```

You can reference it like so:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{img}}">
```