# Request QR Code and show the image using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, google-api, qr-code

My plan is to create a QR code by using an API (such as Google Charts API) and then show the generated QR code on my website. I created a function that requests a QR Code image from Google Chart API:

```
.controller('DealCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=160%20FSU728F29G&coe=UTF-8")
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.qrcode = data;
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.qrcode = status;
  });
})
```

When I try to bind the response as HTML, I get this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="qrcode"></div>
```

[image]

The response seems to be an image (PNG). How can I show this on my website?

Comment: I feel like there is more to this and I'm not sure why you are posting to get the chart.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with this comment.

Comment: Why are you posting to get the qr code?

Comment: The image being returned is binary data vs. Base64. [There is a similar SO question posted here with a possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780147/how-to-return-image-from-http-get-in-angularjs)

Comment: @xkcd149, ah I see what you mean. Google API accepts GET and POST requests, so that is not the issue.

Comment: maybe naive question but the url is the image why don't you show it as is?

Comment: Haha, that is a VERY good question :D I would say that is basically the solution :D

Comment: hahah :)  the simple solutions are always the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use the image url as is for some reason and you want to create the image from the contents you can use this:

```
$http.get(
    "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=160%20FSU728F29G&coe=UTF-8",
    {responseType: 'blob'})
.then(function(response) {

    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( response.data );
    $scope.qrcode = '<img src="'+imageUrl+'"/>';

});
```

demonstrating [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/faseduhozu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Credit goes to [@jan-miksovsky](https://jsfiddle.net/Jan_Miksovsky/yy7Zs/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice that there is a solution for this. However, since this can be solved quite simple by showing the image as is, I will use this solution for the meantime! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The returned data seems to be HTML. So you need to inject the Google HTML into your page, using `ng-bind-html`directive :

```html
<div ng-bind-html="qrcode"></div>
```

Comment: The data is a PNG file, not HTML as far as I can tell. So this did not work.

Comment: Could you get the base64 image ? If yes, then you just have to write `<img data-ng-src='data:image/png;base64,{{qrcode}} />'

Comment: Thank Oliver, I tried this before. It looks like the response from Google is a binary string and not a base64 string, so this does not work either.

Comment: Then try `$scope.qrcode = window.btoa(data);` to encode your binary into base64.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using ng-bind-html http://jsbin.com/lifuparija/edit?html,js,output

But without a more in depth example of what you are trying to accomplish, I feel like this is just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `directive` and then use it in your html code.

1. create directive:

   ```
    angular.module('av.qr', [])
   .directive('avQr', function() {
       return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '',
                scope: {
                         image: '='
              },
              link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                    var qrImage = angular.element(scope.image);
                    elem.append(qrImage);
              }
         }
    })
   ```
2. then in your module inject this directive with module name like below:

   `angular.module('my.module', ['av.qr'])`
3. In your controller append `QR` image to `$scope` as you did:

   ```
   .controller('DealCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?                      cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=160%20FSU728F29G&coe=UTF-8")
           .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.qrcode = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.qrcode = status;
           });
    })
   ```
4. In your `HTML` code use your directive like this:

   ```
       <av-qr image="qrcode"></av-qr>
   ```

** You pass your `qrcode` image to your directive.