# How to display QR code generated from rest controller to angularjs html page?

Tags: angularjs, qr-code

I need to display the QR code image in the html using angularjs. I have a Qr code image in the rest controller and i need to display in the html using angularjs
Here is my angularjs controller with directives used code:

```
$http.post("../rest/a/save").then(function(response){
            $scope.qrcode = response.data;
        });
```

Directive used

```
app.directive('avQr', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '',
        scope: {
                 image: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var qrImage = angular.element(scope.image);
            elem.append(qrImage);
      }
 }
})
```

In the html page tried with these to display got referenced from other suggestions and used it

```
<av-qr image="qrcode"></av-qr>
    <div ng-bind-html="qrcode"></div>
    <img data-ng-src='data:image/png;base64,{{qrcode}} />
```

But not working properly, from the rest controller i am sending the buffered image as response to the js controller.

Can anyone help to me solve this or any other suggestions.

Comment: what do you mean by not working properly? what is the error? What does this directive do? can you please be more descriptive.

Comment: i had referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400499/request-qr-code-and-show-the-image-using-angular-js and tried it

Comment: what type of data your api returns? refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780147/how-to-return-image-from-http-get-in-angularjs

Comment: i have used the scope value in the directives in html

Comment: read the link that I have posted above, You will get your answer there.