# AngularJs get blob with $http.get and extract type from response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I have webApi return me a blob file that I have to display.
how can I know what type is the blob that I got? It could be anything, pdf, doc, jpeg etc.

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: (itemsUrl), responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(function mySucces(res) {
    var byteArray = res.data;
    byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteArray);
    var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: '??????' });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
});
```

or, how can I open blob in a new window without know the file type?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `response.headers()` to get the content type:

```
var config = { responseType: 'blob' };

$http.get(itemsUrl, config).then(function onSuccess(response) {
    var blob = response.data;
    var contentType = response.headers("content-type");
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(fileURL); 
});
```

Consider using `'blob'` as the responseType.

For more information, see [MDN XHR responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType).

Comment: Just for a quick reference if anyone wants to know how to get blob response when using `POST`: `$http.post(url, data, config)`. (See https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#post )

Comment: you are not using your contentType variable, so why did you create it?

Comment: The title of the question says "get blob and extract type from response".