# encrypt/decrypt between Java and JavaScript using Web Crypto API

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, webcrypto-api

I am trining to encrypt/decrypt between Java and JavaScript using Web Crypto API (http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#SP800-38B). I found useful information in this forum but now I am stuck...

Java:

```
    String charset = "UTF-8";

    String secret = "hallo1234567890x";
    String salt = "fqpq6V_Vggn-fR_EiEKFBA";
    byte [] iv = "1111111111111111".getBytes(charset);

    // Get Key
    byte[] key = (salt).getBytes(charset);
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);

    // Generate specs
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    // Instantiate cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal((secret).getBytes());

    //output:
    System.out.print("byte array: ");
    for(int i=0; i<encrypted.length; i++){
        System.out.print(encrypted[i] + "\t");          
    }
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("encrypted string Base64: " + new Base64().encodeAsString(encrypted));
```

The output:

```
   byte array: -116 101 -89 89  33  8   -42 77  -82 79  -39 38  112 68  44  16  
   encrypted string Base64: jGWnWSEI1k2uT9kmcEQsEA==
```

JavaScript:

```
var my_key = "fqpq6V_Vggn-fR_EiEKFBA"; 
var my_counter = new Uint8Array(16); 
for(var i=0;i<16;i++){
    my_counter[i] = 1;
}
var my_data = str2ab("hallo1234567890x");
```

For importKey I use folowing parameters:

```
    kty: "oct",
    k: my_key,
    alg: "A128CBC",
    ext: true,

    name: "AES-CBC",
```

For decrypt I use parameters:

```
    name: "AES-CBC",
    iv: my_counter,
```

I get folowing ArrayBuffer as output: 
`[213, 168, 98, 252, 218, 52, 221, 67, 4, 31, 93, 40, 60, 199, 161, 64, 145, 92, 95, 160, 158, 47, 212, 189, 56, 180, 27, 45, 122, 169, 133, 181, 61, 5, 26, 240, 135, 108, 251, 239, 209, 214, 86, 141, 171, 96, 175, 188]`

With `window.btoa(arraybuffer);` it is: `"W29iamVjdCBBcnJheUJ1ZmZlcl0="`.

I use `ab2str(buf)` and `str2ab(str)` frome: [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers).

```
function ab2str(buf) {
   return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

function str2ab(str) {
   var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
   var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
   for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
       bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   return buf;
}
```

What is missing so that the Java and JavaScript outputs are the same?

Comment: I am having the same problem regarding the fact that the bytes generated in Java are *signed* but the WebCrypto JavaScript API expects it to be *unsigned*. Have you reached any conclusion with your problem?

Comment: @zero where you connected javascript code with java

Comment: Could you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your IVs don't match. A 1 byte is not the same as a "1" in ASCII which is actually 49 in the ASCII table.

Comment: Thanks and yes, there are other problem(s) in the code... I think the problem is the Java encrypts a String and JavaScript a ArrayBuffer. If I convert the ArrayBuffer back to Sting I get charakters that cant be convertet with

Comment: window.btoa(arraybuffer); -> Error Message: "The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."

Comment: You can't use `btoa()` to convert an ArrayBuffer into a string. The "W29iamVjdCBBcnJheUJ1ZmZlcl0=" that you got out is actually Base64 encoded "[object ArrayBuffer]". You probably need to write the reverse function to `str2ab()`. Btw, can you share `str2ab()`?

Comment: sorry, I ment `window.btoa(str2ab(arraybuffer));` (see `str2ab()` and `ab2str()`  above)