# Can't fit file encoding when working with Chrome File System API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I need to read a file which contains a group of  symbols moved 65 in ASCII table. It means, for each symbol I am meant to do:

```
String.fromCharCode('¢'.charCodeAt(0)-65) // returns 'a'
```

But it is not working at all. I have asked friends of mine to do the test using Python   inputting the same file and they got the correct result.

When I try to do the same work with Chrome File System it does not work at all. 
I can't get back the expected symbols. I think it is a problem with my encoding/charset plataform but I can't figure out what is and how fix it.

I have tried opening the file with other encoding:

```
var reader=new FileReader();

reader.readAsText(file, 'windows-1252'); // no success
reader.readAsText(file, 'ISO-8859-2'); // no success
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, your shifted text is no longer *text* by `readAsText` criteria. Trying to read it with any standard codepage is not going to work.

You should read the file as binary with [`readAsArrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer), interpret it as unsigned 8-bit int array, shift the bytes, and then [convert the result to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers).

```
var buf = new Uint8Array(reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file));
buf = buf.map((byte) => byte-65);
var string = new TextDecoder("ascii").decode(buf);
```

Comment: Thank you Xan, I will try it

Comment: Xan, Am I expected to do the same when writing to a file?

Comment: I suppose you could do something similar in reverse (with TextEncoder).

Comment: It seems to work with TextEncoder however when I try to input the file content gotten in the readAsArrayBuffer proposed algorithm it brings a Char with the code `129` appended with my letters.