# How to generate pdf, and send it as http response, so that, on client that able to download as pdf?

Tags: javascript, django, pdf, pdfkit

I am using **pdfkit**, to generate pdf from template. I want to sent it as http response, so that on client side we will able to download as pdf. **But on client side it is getting corrupted. Please tell me why.** I think is there any encoding problem, I think we have to send `encode('utf-8')` in server side code....

**Server side code(django**)

```
address_template_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'address_template.html')

# generate pdf
add_str = render_to_string(address_template_path)
pdfkit.from_string(add_str, file_location)

address_pdf = open(file_location)
response = HttpResponse(address_pdf.read(), 
content_type='application/pdf')  # Generates the response as pdf response.
```

**client-side(javascript+angularjs)**

```
$scope.downloadAddress = function(reqData){

        service.getAddress(reqData).then(function(response){
            if(response.data.error){
                toastr.error(response.data.message ,"Unsuccessful");
            }else{
                var file = new Blob([ str2ab(response.data) ], {
                    type : 'application/pdf'
                });
                //trick to download store a file having its URL
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var a         = document.createElement('a');
                a.href        = fileURL;
                a.target      = '_blank';
                a.download    = envelopeObj.customer_name+'_'+ 'envId_'+envelopeObj.envelope_id+'.pdf';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        });
    };

function str2ab(str) {
          var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
          var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
          for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
            bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          return buf;
        }
```

I get above function `str2ab` from [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

Comment: Not sure what the point is of all that JS. Why not just give the user a link that opens the PDF?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for reply, but requirement is like that, are you got my question?