# Convert Windows-1252 to UTF-8 with JS

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

I have some strings in dutch language. I know how to encode them using PHP

```
$str = iconv( "Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $str );
```

What would be the equivalent in Javascript?

Comment: I'd be interested to see if this is a thing in JS

Comment: @evolutionxbox. Me too.

Comment: Since I have not got any response, I thought of doing the conversion with AJAX but still ended up in issues. So if any one is reading this may be you can see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432964/character-conversion-working-different-for-fgetcsv-and-jquery-get-with-ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows-1252 is a single-byte encoding, which is pretty convenient: you can just build a lookup table.

```php
<?php
$s = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++) {
    $converted = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', chr($i));

    if ($converted === false) {
        $s .= "\xef\xbf\xbd";  # UTF-8 replacement character
    } else {
        $s .= $converted;
    }
}

echo $s;
```

Assuming you want a regular JavaScript string as a result (rather than UTF-8) and that the input is a string where each character’s Unicode codepoint actually represents a Windows-1252 one, the resulting table can be read as UTF-8, put in a JavaScript string literal, and voilà:

```
var WINDOWS_1252 = '\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b\f\r\u000e\u000f\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a\u001b\u001c\u001d\u001e\u001f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~€�‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹Œ�Ž��‘’“”•–—˜™š›œ�žŸ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ';

function fromWindows1252(binaryString) {
    var text = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
        text += WINDOWS_1252.charAt(binaryString.charCodeAt(i));
    }

    return text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could not understand it fully. To best explain my issue I have created a new question. May be you can look at that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432964/convert-windows-1252-to-utf-8-with-ajax

Comment: @KiranDash: Why not encode the CSV in UTF-8 with your original `iconv`? That way you only have to make one round trip to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I did this using brute force, probably not the most elegant, but it works:

```
function bruteForceWindows1252toUTF16(s) {

    for (var i = 0; i < globalWin1252toUTF16table.length; i++) {
        if (s.includes(globalWin1252toUTF16table[i]['win1252'])) {
            s = s.replaceAll(globalWin1252toUTF16table[i]['win1252'], globalWin1252toUTF16table[i]['utf16']);
        }
    }
    return s;
}


const globalWin1252toUTF16table = [
        { win1252:'\xe2\x82\xac', utf16:'\u20AC' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\x9a', utf16:'\u201A' },
        { win1252:'\xc6\x92', utf16:'\u0192' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\x9e', utf16:'\u201E' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\xa6', utf16:'\u2026' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\xa0', utf16:'\u2020' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\xa1', utf16:'\u2021' },
        { win1252:'\xcb\x86', utf16:'\u02C6' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\xb0', utf16:'\u2030' },
        { win1252:'\xc5\xa0', utf16:'\u0160' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\xb9', utf16:'\u2039' },
        { win1252:'\xc5\x92', utf16:'\u0152' },
        { win1252:'\xc5\xbd', utf16:'\u017D' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\x98', utf16:'\u2018' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\x99', utf16:'\u2019' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\x9c', utf16:'\u201C' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\x9d', utf16:'\u201D' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\xa2', utf16:'\u2022' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\x93', utf16:'\u2013' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\x94', utf16:'\u2014' },
        { win1252:'\xcb\x9c', utf16:'\u02DC' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x84\xa2', utf16:'\u2122' },
        { win1252:'\xc5\xa1', utf16:'\u0161' },
        { win1252:'\xe2\x80\xba', utf16:'\u203A' },
        { win1252:'\xc5\x93', utf16:'\u0153' },
        { win1252:'\xc5\xbe', utf16:'\u017E' },
        { win1252:'\xc5\xb8', utf16:'\u0178' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa0', utf16:'\u00A0' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa1', utf16:'\u00A1' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa2', utf16:'\u00A2' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa3', utf16:'\u00A3' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa4', utf16:'\u00A4' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa5', utf16:'\u00A5' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa6', utf16:'\u00A6' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa7', utf16:'\u00A7' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa8', utf16:'\u00A8' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xa9', utf16:'\u00A9' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xaa', utf16:'\u00AA' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xab', utf16:'\u00AB' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xac', utf16:'\u00AC' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xad', utf16:'\u00AD' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xae', utf16:'\u00AE' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xaf', utf16:'\u00AF' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb0', utf16:'\u00B0' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb1', utf16:'\u00B1' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb2', utf16:'\u00B2' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb3', utf16:'\u00B3' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb4', utf16:'\u00B4' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb5', utf16:'\u00B5' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb6', utf16:'\u00B6' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb7', utf16:'\u00B7' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb8', utf16:'\u00B8' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xb9', utf16:'\u00B9' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xba', utf16:'\u00BA' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xbb', utf16:'\u00BB' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xbc', utf16:'\u00BC' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xbd', utf16:'\u00BD' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xbe', utf16:'\u00BE' },
        { win1252:'\xc2\xbf', utf16:'\u00BF' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x80', utf16:'\u00C0' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x81', utf16:'\u00C1' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x82', utf16:'\u00C2' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x83', utf16:'\u00C3' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x84', utf16:'\u00C4' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x85', utf16:'\u00C5' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x86', utf16:'\u00C6' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x87', utf16:'\u00C7' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x88', utf16:'\u00C8' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x89', utf16:'\u00C9' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x8a', utf16:'\u00CA' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x8b', utf16:'\u00CB' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x8c', utf16:'\u00CC' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x8d', utf16:'\u00CD' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x8e', utf16:'\u00CE' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x8f', utf16:'\u00CF' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x90', utf16:'\u00D0' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x91', utf16:'\u00D1' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x92', utf16:'\u00D2' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x93', utf16:'\u00D3' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x94', utf16:'\u00D4' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x95', utf16:'\u00D5' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x96', utf16:'\u00D6' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x97', utf16:'\u00D7' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x98', utf16:'\u00D8' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x99', utf16:'\u00D9' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x9a', utf16:'\u00DA' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x9b', utf16:'\u00DB' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x9c', utf16:'\u00DC' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x9d', utf16:'\u00DD' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x9e', utf16:'\u00DE' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\x9f', utf16:'\u00DF' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa0', utf16:'\u00E0' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa1', utf16:'\u00E1' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa2', utf16:'\u00E2' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa3', utf16:'\u00E3' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa4', utf16:'\u00E4' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa5', utf16:'\u00E5' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa6', utf16:'\u00E6' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa7', utf16:'\u00E7' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa8', utf16:'\u00E8' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xa9', utf16:'\u00E9' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xaa', utf16:'\u00EA' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xab', utf16:'\u00EB' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xac', utf16:'\u00EC' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xad', utf16:'\u00ED' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xae', utf16:'\u00EE' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xaf', utf16:'\u00EF' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb0', utf16:'\u00F0' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb1', utf16:'\u00F1' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb2', utf16:'\u00F2' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb3', utf16:'\u00F3' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb4', utf16:'\u00F4' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb5', utf16:'\u00F5' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb6', utf16:'\u00F6' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb7', utf16:'\u00F7' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb8', utf16:'\u00F8' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xb9', utf16:'\u00F9' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xba', utf16:'\u00FA' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xbb', utf16:'\u00FB' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xbc', utf16:'\u00FC' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xbd', utf16:'\u00FD' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xbe', utf16:'\u00FE' },
        { win1252:'\xc3\xbf', utf16:'\u00FF' }
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, so let me show what worked.

My misinterpreted string came from a ReadableStream. When I ran `await ReadableStreamVar.text()`, the resulting text was replacing all diacritics with strange "�" characters. When I tried to open the same page manually in the browser, it showed correctly, and typing `document.characterSet` in he console I saw the charset was "windows-1252", not UTF-8.

Ry's answer didn't work out because the `text` method in the ReadableStream was already coming with the wrong encoding, replacing all different diacritics with the same � character.

Consulting ReadableStream's API, I didn't found any form of passing the desired charset to the `.text` method, so I tried a different approach: to read the ReadableStream as an array (`ReadableStream.arrayBuffer()`), and it worked. In the array, I could see the diacritic characters had the charcodes for the correct characters. So, I used the TextDecoder API (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)), and my now-functional code looks like this:

```
async function getDocumentTextContent(uri) {
    const response = await fetch(uri, { method: "GET" })
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Problem retrieving the resource. Error message: ${response.statusText}`)
    const dec = new TextDecoder("windows-1252") //Here I can inform the desired charset
    const arrBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
    const ui8array = new Uint8Array(arrBuffer)
    const text = dec.decode(ui8array)
    console.log(text)
    return text
}
```