# Browser localStorage arraybuffer and objects

Tags: javascript, json, html, reactjs, local-storage

I am creating a school project, a secure chat like whatsapp / signal.
https://github.com/andeluvian/React-Chat

The application works ok, its still a mess but what i need help with to continue the project is to create a local storage for registrationId, keyId,IdentityKeyPair, PreKey, SignedPreKey

What i have tested with is the InMemoryStorage and i can see from logs that i can save most of everything in there.

When i cleared the Authentication.Js to create the localStorage i kinda feel like its not really what i should be doing.

At the SubmitHandle(e)

i do

```
window.localStorage.setItem('username', this.state.username);
var registrationid = KeyHelper.generateregistrationId();
window.localstorage.setItem('registrationId', registrationId);
```

At this point everything is fine however when i add identitykeyPair/PreKey/SignedPreKey which is another object i feel like im getting into a mess i use JSON.Stringify to put the objects into localstorage and get Inside Storage

```
preKey:"{"keyId":1,"keyPair":{"pubKey":{},"privKey":{}}}"
```

And using JSON.parse i get:

```
Object
keyId:1
-keyPair: Object
+privKey:Object
+pubKey:Object
```

:D the pub and privkey should be ArrayBuffer. Can someone brave enough help me create this part where i can store my junk into localstorage and also retrieve it?

Ps. I know there is a lot of easy ways and different libraries out there, but I am kinda limited to the project scope and requirements.

-E2E encrypted chat
-Use whisper systems signal protocol

My app uses https://github.com/kentandlime/simple-chat-api as API because the frontend is made from their tutorial.

git elsehow/signal-protocol

I am using the forked library for signal protocol

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API#Storage_limits instead of local storage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

Comment: Hmm i have heard also my teacher say there is a duplicate or it is not necessary to have duplicates, but at the moment I dont know of a better way to store the data of arraybuffer and then load it so it can be used again by the signal protocol

Comment: `KeyHelper.generateIdentityKeyPair().then((identityKeyPair)=>{
          var int32 = new Uint8Array(identityKeyPair.pubKey);
          var int23 = new Uint8Array(identityKeyPair.privKey);

        localStorage.setItem('pubKey', JSON.stringify(int32));
        localStorage.setItem('privKey',JSON.stringify(int23));
        });

var arr1 =localStorage.getItem('privKey');
var arr2 = localStorage.getItem('pubKey');
var a1 = new Uint8Array(arr1);
var a2 = new Uint8Array(arr2);

let identityKeyPair ={
pubKey: a2.buffer,
privKey: a1.buffer

};

console.log(identityKeyPair);`