# Node.js encode ISO8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, node.js, unicode, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have an application that allows users to persist strings to a database and those strings may contain emojis. The problem I have is an emoji such as  will get stored in MySQL as `ðŸ˜Š`

When I retrieve this string using a PHP MySQL client and render it in a web browser, it renders fine probably because the `Content-Type` is set to UTF-8. When I try to read the string in node.js, I get back what I think is the ISO8859-1 encoding a literal `ðŸ˜Š`. The charset on the table is set to `latin1` and that's where I'm getting ISO8859-1 from.

What's the right way to encode the string in node.js so that I can see the emoji and not the encoding set by MySQL when I `console.log` the string?

Comment: How about simply fixing the column charset instead?

Comment: @zerkms Unfortunately that's not an option at this time, ideally I'd be able to solve this on the client. I do understand that your suggestion is the ideal solution, however.

Comment: It looks like you need to convert the unicode codepoints to the corresponding iso8859-1 charcters. Then use the array buffer to assemble a utf string from raw bytes. The latter can be find http://stackoverflow.com/a/11058858/251311 and for the former try https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite Alternatively to the iconv-lite you might simply created the conversion table manually, since it's tiny

Comment: @zerkms - ISO8859-1 has no codes for Emoji, so it cannot be shoehorned into that charset.

Comment: @RickJames I did not say it has, my answer does the same what you suggested in mysql, but in js

Answer (score 13):

`ðŸ˜Š` is [*Mojibake*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for .  Interpreting the former as latin1, you get hex `F09F988A`, which is the `UTF-8` hex for that Emoji.

(Note:  `UTF-8` outside MySQL is equivalent to `utf8mb4` inside MySQL.)

In MySQL, you must have the column/table declared with `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  You must also state that the data being stored/fetched is encoded `utf8mb4`.  Note: `utf8` will not suffice.

Do a `SELECT HEX(col) FROM ...` to see if you get that hex for that Emoji.  If that is the case *and* the column is currently `latin1`, then part of the fix is to carefully convert the column to utf8mb4.  That is, you have `CHARACTER SET latin1`, but have UTF-8 bytes in it; this will leave bytes alone while fixing charset.  Assuming the column is already `VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL`, then do this 2-step ALTER:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(111) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL;
```

Virtually any other conversion mechanism will make a worse mess.

As for establishing the connection correctly, it goes something like this for node.js:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... , charset : 'utf8mb4'});
```

Comment: If the column is a CHAR (vs VARCHAR) does any of this change? I'd imagine the answer is no, but when I convert all the Mojibake bytes turn into literal question marks `?`

Comment: See the link again -- question marks is caused by something else.  Check the "best practice" list.  `CHAR` tends to waste space unless the strings are fixed length.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need, and should not convert encoding. Just use the right protocols. If you send the HTML page in UTF-8, the browser will send the data back to your server in UTF-8.

Then you want to store the data to your database which is in `latin1`, that won't work at all. You must convert your database to UTF-8 as well. That includes the database, the tables, and eventually the columns themselves. Also make sure that your database client is configured to connect in UTF-8, because the client itself has to declare its encoding.

Once you have the whole data-flux in UTF-8, everything will work flawlessly.

*Server -> GET HTML -> POST -> Server -> SQL Client -> Database -> Table -> Column*

Comment: If you read the comments in the original post, you'll see that changing the database to UTF-8 is not an option at this time.

Comment: I see that, but it will have to be an option someday because using dirty tricks to convert encoding is only a gateway to hell opening. OP's team should talk about it urgently and take a decision accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to use [`iconv`](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv)*(A simple ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 conversion)*

From this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mallendeo/44d5127b40ccb659b609)

```
var iconv = require('iconv');

function toUTF8(body) {
  // convert from iso-8859-1 to utf-8
  var ic = new iconv.Iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8');
  var buf = ic.convert(body);
  return buf.toString('utf-8');
}
```

here if you pass anything in ISO-8859-1 , it will return it's UTF-8.

for example,

```
toUTF8("ðŸ˜Š");
```

will return

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I get `Ã°Å¸Ë` returned.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a super dirty way to convert it back:

```js
    const isoToUtfTable = {
      'ð': 0xf0,
      'Ÿ': 0x9f,
      '˜': 0x98,
      'Š': 0x8a
    };
    
    function convertISO8859ToUtf8(s) {
      const buf = new Uint8Array([...s].map(c => isoToUtfTable[c]));
      return String.fromCharCode(...buf)
    }
    
    function decode_utf8(s) {
      return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
    }
    
    console.log(decode_utf8(convertISO8859ToUtf8('ðŸ˜Š')))
```

Now you simply need to complete the `isoToUtfTable` table (it's small, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Comment: There has to be a better way than to manually fill a lookup table. If this is the best answer I'll mark it as such, but I'm going to wait to see if there's a more reliable method first.

Comment: @randombits you may take https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite or any other library to convert them. This is simply a way to do that without bringing dependencies.

Comment: I've been trying to get it to work with iconv-lite, I don't mind adding a dependency - can't seem to get it back to UTF-8, though. Just displays the string literals that are in the database.

Comment: would it be possible to update your answer to also show how this is done using iconv-lite?

Comment: @randombits I tried using their https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/blob/master/encodings/sbcs-data-generated.js but apparently the 3 latest of 4 characters in `ðŸ˜Š` are not that valid ISO-8859-1 characters. So, I don't know the other way of fixing it than just creating a tiny 255 elements (may be even 127 if the lower half is the same) table.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to look at [node-iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv).

```
const iconv = new Iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8');
const buffer = iconv.convert(something);
console.log(buffer);
console.log(buffer.toString('UTF8'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a full answer from @zerkms solution

```js
 const isoToUtfTable = {
'€':0x80,
'na':0x81,
'‚':0x82,
'ƒ':0x83,
'„':0x84,
'…':0x85,
'†':0x86,
'‡':0x87,
'ˆ':0x88,
'‰':0x89,
'Š':0x8a,
'‹':0x8b,
'Œ':0x8c,
'na':0x8d,
'Ž':0x8e,
'na':0x8f,
'na':0x90,
'‘':0x91,
'’':0x92,
'“':0x93,
'”':0x94,
'•':0x95,
'–':0x96,
'—':0x97,
'˜':0x98,
'™':0x99,
'š':0x9a,
'›':0x9b,
'œ':0x9c,
'na':0x9d,
'ž':0x9e,
'Ÿ':0x9f,
'NSBP':0xa0,
'¡':0xa1,
'¢':0xa2,
'£':0xa3,
'¤':0xa4,
'¥':0xa5,
'¦':0xa6,
'§':0xa7,
'¨':0xa8,
'©':0xa9,
'ª':0xaa,
'«':0xab,
'¬':0xac,
'SHY':0xad,
'®':0xae,
'¯':0xaf,
'°':0xb0,
'±':0xb1,
'²':0xb2,
'³':0xb3,
'´':0xb4,
'µ':0xb5,
'¶':0xb6,
'·':0xb7,
'¸':0xb8,
'¹':0xb9,
'º':0xba,
'»':0xbb,
'¼':0xbc,
'½':0xbd,
'¾':0xbe,
'¿':0xbf,
'À':0xc0,
'Á':0xc1,
'Â':0xc2,
'Ã':0xc3,
'Ä':0xc4,
'Å':0xc5,
'Æ':0xc6,
'Ç':0xc7,
'È':0xc8,
'É':0xc9,
'Ê':0xca,
'Ë':0xcb,
'Ì':0xcc,
'Í':0xcd,
'Î':0xce,
'Ï':0xcf,
'Ð':0xd0,
'Ñ':0xd1,
'Ò':0xd2,
'Ó':0xd3,
'Ô':0xd4,
'Õ':0xd5,
'Ö':0xd6,
'×':0xd7,
'Ø':0xd8,
'Ù':0xd9,
'Ú':0xda,
'Û':0xdb,
'Ü':0xdc,
'Ý':0xdd,
'Þ':0xde,
'ß':0xdf,
'à':0xe0,
'á':0xe1,
'â':0xe2,
'ã':0xe3,
'ä':0xe4,
'å':0xe5,
'æ':0xe6,
'ç':0xe7,
'è':0xe8,
'é':0xe9,
'ê':0xea,
'ë':0xeb,
'ì':0xec,
'í':0xed,
'î':0xee,
'ï':0xef,
'ð':0xf0,
'ñ':0xf1,
'ò':0xf2,
'ó':0xf3,
'ô':0xf4,
'õ':0xf5,
'ö':0xf6,
'÷':0xf7,
'ø':0xf8,
'ù':0xf9,
'ú':0xfa,
'û':0xfb,
'ü':0xfc,
'ý':0xfd,
'þ':0xfe,
'ÿ':0xff }





let offsetArray = [];
function convertISO8859ToUtf8Simple(s) {
    offsetArray = [];
    const buf = new Uint8Array([...s].map((c, index) => 
        {
            if(isoToUtfTable[c]) {
                if(offsetArray.length > 0 && offsetArray[offsetArray.length -1]+3 < index) {
                    offsetArray.push(index);
                }
                if(offsetArray.length == 0) {
                    offsetArray.push(index);
                }
            }
            
            return isoToUtfTable[c];
        }
        
        ));
      return String.fromCharCode(...buf);
      
    }

    
function decode_utf8(s) {
      return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
    }


function  emojiStringToArray(str) {
  split = str.split(/([\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF])/);
  arr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<split.length; i++) {
    char = split[i]
    if (char !== "" && !char.includes('\u0000')) {
      arr.push(char);
    }
  }
  return arr;
};


const string = 'hello ðŸ˜ŒðŸ˜Œ with some emojis ðŸ˜Š ';

function finalString(s) {
    const emojis = emojiStringToArray(decode_utf8(convertISO8859ToUtf8Simple(s)));

    for(let i = 0; i<offsetArray.length; i++){ 
        let position = 0;
        if (i == 0) {
            position = offsetArray[i];
        } else {
            position = (i * -3) + offsetArray[i] + (i);
        }
            s =  [s.slice(0, position), emojis[i], s.slice(position+4)].join('');
    }
    return s;
}

console.log(finalString(string));
```