# How to read SOAP request response body, when server returns 500 Internal server Error in React native App

Tags: react-native, soap, axios, http-status-code-500

I am calling SOAP request using axios in my react native app.
If the SOAP Request fails the server sends back 500 Internal Server Error.
Is there a way to retrieve the message body when the server returns a 500 internal Server Error which contains the fault code.?

I am trying to get the error.response.body in the catch block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [catching error body using axios post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017822/catching-error-body-using-axios-post)

Comment: I have tried it but It throws undefined.