# what character encoding can yield identical results for md5 with an array buffer?

Tags: javascript, md5, filereader

So, if I do:

```
fileReader.onload = function (e) {
    console.log(md5(e.target.result));
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

I get: df9206f11a5c4fc7841fca94522f19f2

But, if I do:

```
fileReader.onload = function (e) {
    console.log(md5(e.target.result));
};
fileReader.readAsText(blob);
```

I get a completely different hash.  I assume this is due to character encoding?  So I am curious, what encoding can I use which will result in an identical hash?

Comment: and.. why is this getting down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `readAsArrayBuffer()` will read the source as a "pure" *byte*-range independent of what the data represents and its byte-order.

Using `readAsText()` without any encoding options will take *two and two* bytes from the source, assume and convert to a single UTF-16 (or UCS-2) character which will produce a completely different result, as you noticed.

If you know the source is in for example UTF-8 text format you can read it using the optional [encoding options](https://devdocs.io/dom/filereader/readastext) with `readAsText(blob[, encoding])` (see [supported encoding types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder#Parameters)).

Any common single-byte encoding page should suffer, in that case, as MD5 signatures as text are always within the ASCII range - the main issue then, is that it needs to be read as *single byte* and not double as with UTF-16/USC-2.

A different problem *could* be byte-order. For this case an alternative is to read it as ArrayBuffer and then use [TextDecoder](https://devdocs.io/dom/textdecoder) (see [example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902334/1693593)) with correct byte-order (there is a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) option available (`ignoreBOM`) for this approach), e.g. little-endian or big-endian (denoted as "le" and "be", f.ex. "utf-16be", in the previous linked encoder types).

Comment: great, thanks!  And.. any idea why this question was down voted so much?  I had no idea this would be such an inappropriate question on here.