# Converting array buffer in string

Tags: javascript, typescript, arraybuffer

I am stuck in converting arraybuffer to string in typescript (angular 4 project). Any help is highly appreciated.

Code output is showing string but with  this sign - �

Required Output :

## PROGRAM "Digitala †rsredovisningen"

Getting Output :

## PROGRAM "Digitala �rsredovisningen"

```js
  
ab2str(arraybuffer) {
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arraybuffer));
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this:

```
function uintToString(uintArray) {
    var encodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uintArray),
        decodedString = decodeURIComponent(escape(encodedString));
    return decodedString;
}
```

Maybe this will help:

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/164/how-to-convert-an-uint8array-to-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This will allow unicode characters

```
ab2str(arraybuffer) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(arraybuffer));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Zinc , but Uint16Array shows output something like 䘣䅌䝇⁁ਰ倣佒則䵁∠楄楧慴慬蘠獲

Answer (score 0):

From [this reference](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String) you can check the following:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

Additionally, if you [can use](https://caniuse.com/#search=textdecoder) using `TextEncoder` and `TextEncoder`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902334/1314706).

Comment: function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
} - Same code I am using, It is not working

Comment: Can you post a codepen, a jsbin or similar with an example of your issue so we can help?

Comment: I just found  -  String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [134]) - this isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

I had a SHA256 hash that i needed to convert to String.

```
function ab2str(hashBuffer) {
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
    const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
    return hashHex;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the same problem as Shifali singla (chinese characters) just change this:

> **return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(arraybuffer));**

to this

> **return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arraybuffer));**

the buffer is probably coming in a unit8array and not in a unit16array