# How to receive binary data from Websocket in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I need to convert binary data to string.

I have this code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(url);
ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
ws.on('message', function(body) {
  console.log(body);
  console.log(body.toString());
});
```

And I got in console:

```
ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 266 }
[object ArrayBuffer]
```

From next code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(url);
ws.on('message', function(body) {
  console.log(body);
  console.log(body.toString());
});
```

I got:

```
<Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5d 92 c1 4b 1b 41 14 c6 bf 37 9b 51 82 84 a2 29 88 86 45 f1 50 2f 12 77 d5 54 14 d4 80 07 8f ... >
```

And something like this:

```
4ƿ7�Q���)��E�P/w�TԀ�JB[�B�S4�VA��Pza/"=ToC��[Ͻ�'Z�Z�^���7wXv�7�|�͛I@�^~��J�G��c�ʴ�Co�<��_70K1���~����iY31;��zc��<B���Q��~�+�F��_M(= N^I��}BU?U�̲��)���L���=,p��1\��8�[���[c�S]K����ܖIy.���Ơg\q��T���R�
���������8��#O;����f���n9z��CF:��Y��Xfl��--��U�QM�z�d֧�Ó�H�                                                      �}1yć�f�C����/2��"�TH���ԅʛ�w)E�R4
```

In browser I got this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/az8gS.png

Comment: What are you sending, and how?

Comment: I don't have access to the server code

Comment: So, what is the server supposed to be sending? It's obviously not a string. It is compressed? Encrypted? Is it a binary representation of structured data?

Comment: I don't have any assumptions. Is there a way to find out if it is compressed or something?

Comment: Uh, what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to get advice on how to make this binary data readable

Comment: It seems your buffer may contain gzipped data. Try decompressing it first.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is only: I need to convert binary data to string, right ?

Have a look here: [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why it's converting to: `¦ÕÑÈvÙ}æq@ÆÃ¸ÊX)%Æ­eõ*ñìr5ÄQ×8¤&L0¬yfLîÂô`
I tried `ab2str(buf)` and got this again.

Comment: Maybe something like   var buffer = new Uint8Array(message);  console.log(buffer.toString());