# Sending String command to BLE in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

im new in ionic, right now i'm trying to send a "code" in string.
which the string consist of a few packets data in HEX.
eg. V1-FC03-2ED1-FE01

V1 is the sequence, then after the first - is the first packet "FC03"
the code successfully send to my arduino using serial monitor on pc.
[arduino serial monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldniJ.png)

now i want to send it trough BLE using ionic.
i follow the example on github on doing the BLE.
it works if send 1 or 0.

here is the function in ionic codes that going to send to arduino after button pressed

```
onPowerSwitchChange(event) {
console.log('onPowerSwitchChange');
let value = this.power ? 1 : 0;
let buffer = new Uint8Array([value]).buffer;
console.log('Power Switch Property ' + this.power);
this.ble.write(this.peripheral.id, LIGHTBULB_SERVICE, SWITCH_CHARACTERISTIC, buffer).then(
  () => this.setStatus('Light is ' + (this.power ? 'on' : 'off')),
  e => this.showAlert('Unexpected Error', 'Error updating power switch')
);
}
```

here i tried to change

```
 let value = this.power ? 1 : 0;
```

to

```
 let value = "V1-FC03-2ED1-FE01";
```

but when compile, got error

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer'. Property 'byteLength' is
        missing in type 'string[]'.
  L68:  let value = "V1-FC03-2ED1-FE01";
  L69:  let buffer = new Uint8Array([value]).buffer;
  L70:  console.log('Power Switch Property ' + this.power);
```

hopefully someone can help me on this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you as I'm not a programmer by trade... but I wanted to send a "2" as string and it turned out that I had to do it like this:

```
  var data = new Uint8Array(1);
  data[0] = 50;
```

With 50 being the Uint8Array equivalent of 2

Currently I'm trying to read from the BLE in the opposite direction to no effect so please keep us posted as to your progress.