# Base64 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I send some image from java.
I need to do URLEncoder because I need to send the Base64 data in the URL

```
String base64Document = Base64.encode(documentBytes);
base64Document = URLEncoder.encode(base64Document, "UTF-8"); // This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIMEformat
```

But when I load this data I dont have any image.

I need a way to decode this.

My code works for canvas but not for image

```
 console.log("Encoded" + vm.documentData.base64Document);
    vm.documentData.base64Document = urlDecode(vm.documentData.base64Document);
    console.log("Decoded" + vm.documentData.base64Document);


   // Decode Safe URL Base64
function urlDecode(encoded) {
    encoded = encoded.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    while (encoded.length % 4)
      encoded += '=';
      return new ArrayBuffer(encoded || '', 'base64').toString('utf8');
};
```

html

```
  <img class="document" src="data:image/png;base64,{{vm.documentData.base64Document}}" />
```

> GET data:image/png;base64,[object ArrayBuffer] net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayBuffer.prototype.toString` will always return [object ArrayBuffer].

If you need to convert it into a string, I suggest to read this answer: [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)