# AngularJS - Spring - Return a status code and text when query result is empty

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I have an AngularJS project that requests to a Spring Boot app.

Then the Spring Boot app will return data in bytes that can be later be downloaded as an Excel file like so:

Spring Boot controller app:

```
public ResponseEntity generateExcelReport(@RequestBody ArrayList<SearchCriteria> searchCriteriaList) {
    Query dynamicQuery = new Query();

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment");

    try {
        List<Investment> resultList = investmentService.findByDynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);

        Workbook workbook = myService.generateExcelReport(resultList);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(out);

        byte[] bArray = out.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(bArray);

        workbook.close();
        out.close();
        out.flush();

        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(responseHeaders)
            .contentLength(resource.getByteArray().length)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
            .body(resource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e);
    }
}
```

But I want to improve this code by returning a `ResponseEntity` with status 204 if the `resultList` is empty like so:

Update :

```
    public ResponseEntity generateExcelReport(@RequestBody ArrayList < SearchCriteria > searchCriteriaList) {
    Query dynamicQuery = new Query();

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment");

    try {
        List < Investment > resultList = investmentService.findByDynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);

        // If there are no results found, throw a 204 No Content back to front-end
        // So that there is no Excel generation involved.
        if (resultList.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body("There are no results found.");
        }

        ...

        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(responseHeaders)
            .contentLength(resource.getByteArray().length)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
            .body(resource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e);
    }
}
```

This is the AngularJS Snippet for the front-end side

```
ReportService.generateExcelReport($scope.searchCriteriaList)
.then(function (responseObj) {
    if (responseObj.status === 204) {
        return SweetAlert.swal("No results", responseObj.data, "warning");
    } 

    // responseObj.data = Excel bytes returned by Spring in this case
    var blob = new Blob([responseObj.data], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    });

    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "myreport.xlsx");

    swal.close();
})
```

But my problem is, my $http.post request contains a `responseType: "arraybuffer"` as part of the request.

Because of this,
 even if I return a String on the back-end side like this:

`return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body("There are no results found.");`

I still get an arraybuffer in the response data. And I can't access the String.

$http.post request snippet:

```
generateExcelReport: function (searchCriteriaList) {
    var requestConfig = {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        headers: {
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment"
        }
    };

    var url =  "my-api/generate-paiwi-reports-excel"

    return $http.post(url, searchCriteriaList, requestConfig);
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm getting into the right direction. Please help. =)
Thank you very much in advance. =)

Comment: Could you try the **resultList empty** case using postman, soapui or another rest client tool? This will help you to validate if your api is returning in case of error, plain json or another content type.

Comment: Hi @JRichardsz, thank you for your comment. In this case I tested it via Insomnia REST client and I got the response I've been expecting. As such, my problem in my angularJS service is that I always want my response converted to arraybuffer as this is the way in angularJS to download Excel bytes coming from the backend. But I managed to have a solution for this, but I'm not quite sure that it is the best one for the job. Will be posting my solution in a few.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have a solution for this one, but I'm not sure if it's the best one for the job.

Since I still have no way (I can think of) to remove the `responseType: "arraybuffer"` in my `$http.post` request, I will always have an `arraybuffer` as a response back to my controller.

Even if I just return a string from Spring back-end, I will have an ArrayBuffer.

But thankfully there is a Web API called [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder) that can decode my ArrayBuffer response to a string.

I discovered this thanks to an answer in an existing question here in SO. [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902334/7209628)

This is my whole code now:

Spring back-end;

```
List<Investment> resultList = investmentService.findByDynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);

// By throwing this HttpStatus, it will be in the .catch function of the Promise.
if (resultList.isEmpty()) {
    return ResponseEntity
        .status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        .body("There are no results found.");
}
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
// AngularJS $http.post request returns an httpPromise containing different properties        
ReportService.generateExcelReport($scope.searchCriteriaList)
.then(function(responseObj) {

    var dateToday = ReportService.getFullDateToday();
    var fileName = "MyReport_" + dateToday + ".xlsx";

    // responseObj.data = Excel bytes returned by Spring in this case
    var blob = new Blob([responseObj.data], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    });

    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);

    swal.close();
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // I forced Spring to throw a 406 - Not Acceptable error when mongoDB query result is 0.
    if (error.status === 406) {
        var decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
        var errorMessage = decoder.decode(error.data);

        return SweetAlert.swal("No Results", errorMessage, "warning");
    }

    console.error(error);
    SweetAlert.swal("Ooops!", "Something went wrong...", "error");
})
```