# How to use nodejs crypto in cryptoMd5Method of EvaporateJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, aws-sdk, evaporate.js

I'm using EvaporateJS in a react project which uses webpack.

As described in the [documentation](https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS/wiki/Evaporate.create()) I used the following:

(**I don't want to use the aws-sdk because of the package size which btw works properly**)

```
cryptoMd5Method: function (data) { 
 return crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest('base64'); 
}
```

But 'data' is type of ArrayBuffer. So I tried converting it to string.

```
cryptoMd5Method: function (data) { 
    var enc = new TextDecoder();
    var dataString = enc.decode(data);
    var computed = crypto.createHash('md5').update(dataString).digest('base64');
    return computed ;
}
```

But that doesn't compute the digest correctly.

---

So, what should be the solution for this (considering the nodejs crypto option)?

Also alternatively, how to import just `AWS.util.crypto` module without referencing the whole `aws-sdk` ? This will help me keep the bundle small.

Comment: You can build aws-sdk with just what you need and nothing else. Follow this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/building-sdk-for-browsers.html

Comment: "But the problem is 'data' is ArrayBuffer" - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @IvanRubinson param data is ArrayBuffer of int type. crypto.createHash('md5').update( ) ---> expects a string param.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Import browser compatible packages:

`import MD5 from 'js-md5';
import { sha256 as SHA256 } from 'js-sha256';`

2) Declare functions:

`const md5 = (x) => { const o = MD5.create(); o.update(x); return o.base64(); };
const sha256 = (x) => { const o = SHA256.create(); o.update(x); return o.hex(); };`

3) Usage in config:

`...
 computeContentMd5: true,
 cryptoMd5Method: (_) => md5(_), 
 cryptoHexEncodedHash256: (_) => sha256(_),
...`

Comment: It worked! Even though I was hoping to get a solution around 'Crypto' but these 2 libraries are way smaller than the 'aws' sdk size.

Answer (score 0):

The entire aws-sdk is indeed big, however for front-end (browsers) you can build a smaller artifact that includes only what you need.
Follow the instructions over at the [amazon docs - Building the SDK for Browsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/building-sdk-for-browsers.html).

For converting ArrayBuffer to string to pass it to the `update()` method of the hashing algorithm, see: [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers).