# Vue upload image from asset or public folder

Tags: vue.js

I have a image on Asset folder name xyz.png

in component folder I have a file called helloworld.vue that contain a button called upload

when user click on upload button I need to post the xyz.png to a api.

```
<template>
  <button @click="upload">upload</button>
</template>
```

and the function

```
upload(){
var img = require("../assets/xyz.png");( I have to load the image properly here )
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", img);

//here I am posting the data to api with header
}
```

Comment: I don't know but what is the question. File is not uploading or you want code for uploading file?

Comment: You should convert `img` from String to ArrayBuffer - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11058858

Comment: @PatelPratik I want to load image in img variable as I like we select or upload image using html input and post that on the url.

Comment: but Uploadcare not support any array buffer @IVO GELOV

Comment: What do they support ? If they support `FormData` - then be aware that `FormData` supports appending ArrayBuffer into it. However, if you instead want the user to choose an image from his computer - then you need a normal `<input type="file">` and it has nothing to do with `../assets/xyz.png`