# Force percent-encode in JS

Tags: javascript

How can I percent-encode a string like `"ü"` such that it comes out as `"%C3%BC"`?

Here's my current implementation:

```
function percentEncode(ch) {
    return '%' + ch.codePointAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2,'0');
}
```

But that encodes it as `'%FC'`.

`encodeURIComponent` handles it correctly, but I need to encode some characters which `encodeURIComponent` refuses to encode, so I can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

```js
const UTF8_ENCODER = new TextEncoder();

function percentEncode(str) {
    return Array.from(UTF8_ENCODER.encode(str)).map(i => '%' + i.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2,'0')).join('');
}

console.log(percentEncode('ü'))
```

[credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902334/65387)