# How to convert a dropped image to a feature in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, exif-js

I'm using the [DragAndDrop](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/DragAndDrop.js#L238-L250) interaction in OpenLayers. I'm trying to drop an image that contains a geospatial location in its metadata to create a feature out of it.

I created a Format to read the file using the [Exif-JS](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) library.
By default, Format objects in OpenLayers read the content of files as text.

How can I take the returned text and convert it back to a **blob** or an **ArrayBuffer** ? Exif-JS won't recognize a string.

I am not allowed to edit the library, but while testing, I confirmed that returning `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);`was working fine to recreate a blob and send it to the exif-js library.

Is there a way to make it work with OpenLayers converting the file as text first?

Comment: Check this post [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

Comment: `ol/format/MVT` reads features from an ArrayBuffer, see the source code https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/format/MVT.js

Comment: The library [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr) can be used.