# Using native javascript / subtleCrypto to encrypt using RSA

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am trying to follow the webdocs for `subtleCrypto`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt

> To use RSA-OAEP, pass an RsaOaepParams object.

How is the `RSA` key supposed to be formatted? The following code is just using plaintext `rsaPublicKey` and `rsaPrivateKey`: how should they be changed

```
let rsaPublicKey = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3 ..."

function encrypt(rsaPublicKey, msg) {
    let emsg = new TextEncoder().encode(msg)
    let encrypted = crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP"
        },
        rsaPublicKey,
        msg
    );
    return encrypted
}
```

```
let rsaPrivateKey = "MIIEvQIBADU ..."
function decrypt(rsaPrivateKey, encrypted) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
    {
      name: "RSA-OAEP"
    },
    rsaPrivateKey,
    encrypted
  );
}
```

Here is the (probably incorrect) code attempting to do the round trip:

```
let enc = encrypt(rsaKey, "hello world!") // ERROR on this line
console.log(enc)
let dec = decrypt(rsaPrivateKey, enc)
console.log(dec)
```

The error is:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'encrypt' on 'SubtleCrypto': parameter 2 is not of type 'CryptoKey'.

So how should the public (and private) keys be encoded/ formatted?

Comment: It's not just you OP, these docs are pretty bad. I'm trying to help with an answer though, I'm sure you will get help with this.

Comment: The key can be imported in different formats, the private one typically in _PKCS#8_ format, the public one typically in _spki_ format. The method that must be used for this is [`crypto.subtle.importKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey). The keys are expected to be DER encoded, i.e. PEM encoded keys must be DER encoded first. However, the public key you use seems to be in OpenSSH format, which is not supported to my knowledge, so it would have to be converted first.

Comment: @Topaco Pls make an answer thx

Comment: @MaartenBodewes  It was not begging: it is an opportunity to be recognized for having provided useful info.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Web Crypto API provides the [`SubtleCrypto.importKey()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey) method for the import of keys, which supports various key formats, in particular the *PKCS#8* format (ASN.1 DER encoding of the `PrivateKeyInfo` structure, see [RFC5208 sec 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208#section-5)) for private keys and the *X.509* format (ASN.1 DER encoding of `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure, or SPKI for short, see [RFC5280 sec 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1)) for public keys. The keys are expected in DER encoding. If they are in PEM encoding, they must first be converted. For this purpose, the header and footer must be removed and the rest must be Base64 decoded.

Example for the import of a public PEM encoded key in *X.509* format and the encryption of a plaintext:

```js
// PEM encoded X.509 key
const publicKey = 
`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAunF5aDa6HCfLMMI/MZLT
5hDk304CU+ypFMFiBjowQdUMQKYHZ+fklB7GpLxCatxYJ/hZ7rjfHH3Klq20/Y1E
bYDRopyTSfkrTzPzwsX4Ur/l25CtdQldhHCTMgwf/Ev/buBNobfzdZE+Dhdv5lQw
KtjI43lDKvAi5kEet2TFwfJcJrBiRJeEcLfVgWTXGRQn7gngWKykUu5rS83eAU1x
H9FLojQfyia89/EykiOO7/3UWwd+MATZ9HLjSx2/Lf3g2jr81eifEmYDlri/OZp4
OhZu+0Bo1LXloCTe+vmIQ2YCX7EatUOuyQMt2Vwx4uV+d/A3DP6PtMGBKpF8St4i
GwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

importPublicKeyAndEncrypt();
    
async function importPublicKeyAndEncrypt() {

    const plaintext = 'This text will be encoded UTF8 and may contain special characters like § and €.';
                
    try {
        const pub = await importPublicKey(publicKey);
        const encrypted = await encryptRSA(pub, new TextEncoder().encode(plaintext));
        const encryptedBase64 = window.btoa(ab2str(encrypted));
        console.log(encryptedBase64.replace(/(.{64})/g, "$1\n")); 
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function importPublicKey(spkiPem) {       
    return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "spki",
        getSpkiDer(spkiPem),
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP",
            hash: "SHA-256",
        },
        true,
        ["encrypt"]
    );
}

async function encryptRSA(key, plaintext) {
    let encrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP"
        },
        key,
        plaintext
    );
    return encrypted;
}

function getSpkiDer(spkiPem){
    const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
    const pemFooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    var pemContents = spkiPem.substring(pemHeader.length, spkiPem.length - pemFooter.length);
    var binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    return str2ab(binaryDerString); 
}

//
// Helper
//

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058858
function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}
    
function ab2str(buf) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
}
```

And the counterpart, the import of a private PEM encoded key in *PKCS#8* format and the decryption of the ciphertext:

```js
// PEM encoded PKCS#8 key
const privateKey = 
`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`;

importPrivateKeyAndDecrypt();
    
async function importPrivateKeyAndDecrypt() {

    // A ciphertext produced with the first code
    const ciphertextB64 = "q/g0YQ+CbFwCb9QxAeKk/X8vjUUKpBGCVe6OvFoBlTfRF24BQlWpLFhxVQv+Gn29CzAXfSJjU+C8taYXQ4wofyOaRx0etkATDbmIV1gVdxNnqVKTx2RSj1L3uACZ3aWYIGRjtaBMBNAW81mPEjxEWCvRW3uI/rOn3LAc4N05CkofOnsIpaafgcEjhZoTxp1Dpkm328bwRJ3g1Dn+vQk6JBiAXSiF7GHvMvnD6q+CQiO1dcv0lrrXlibE8/P2LHWpqQ9g5xWWUHl70q2WB+IxLgX9OkqX8XQ1GHjP5EaQFfo1HerBpa+Uf5DaienI/XT4n64DWM1S7t0dbhFDskc9HQ==";
        
    try {
        const priv = await importPrivateKey(privateKey);
        const decrypted = await decryptRSA(priv, str2ab(window.atob(ciphertextB64)));
        console.log(decrypted);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function importPrivateKey(pkcs8Pem) {     
    return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "pkcs8",
        getPkcs8Der(pkcs8Pem),
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP",
            hash: "SHA-256",
        },
        true,
        ["decrypt"]
    );
}

async function decryptRSA(key, ciphertext) {
    let decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP"
        },
        key,
        ciphertext
    );
    return new TextDecoder().decode(decrypted);
}

function getPkcs8Der(pkcs8Pem){
    const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pemFooter = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    var pemContents = pkcs8Pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pkcs8Pem.length - pemFooter.length);
    var binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    return str2ab(binaryDerString); 
}

//
// Helper
//
    
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058858
function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}
    
function ab2str(buf) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
}
```

Note that your public key is specified in [SSH public key format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6.6), which cannot be processed by `importKey` and therefore has to be converted to *X.509* format first, e.g. with [*ssh-keygen*](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1).