# Convert file's domstring to arraybuffer (bytes) - javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, file

I read image file as 'File' object in JavaScript, and then converted it to DomString using -

`URL.createObjectURL(File)`

Now, I needed to convert this `DomString` represented Image file back to `ArrayBuffer`. Is there a method to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

Comment: This seems related to string. I've a requirement for image file. Image -> DomString (URL.createObjectURL) -> File/ArrayBuffer

Comment: Just store that File at the first step.