# How to create a hash using Web Crypto API?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to create SHA-1 hash on the client-side. I'm trying to do this with Web Crypto API but when I'm comparing the output to what various online tools give me, the result is completely different. I think the problem is in ArrayBuffer to Hex conversion. Here is my code:

```
function generateHash() {
            var value = "mypassword";
            var crypto = window.crypto;
            var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(value);
            var hash_bytes = crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-1", buffer);
            hash_bytes.then(value => document.write([...new Uint8Array(value)].map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')));
        }
```

Output of `document.write` should be:

```
91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2
```

But it's not, I get a completely different hash of different length (should be 40). Could I have some advise on the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Any advise guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be more the input conversion from a string to an `ArrayBuffer`. E.g. with [`str2ab()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058858) the code works:

```js
generateHash();

function generateHash() {
    var value = "mypassword";
    var crypto = window.crypto;
    var buffer = str2ab(value); // Fix
    var hash_bytes = crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-1", buffer);
    hash_bytes.then(value => document.write([...new Uint8Array(value)].map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')));
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058858
function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

with the expected output:

```
91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the debugger, it looks like `var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(value);` results in `buffer` being an empty ArrayBuffer.  The text string stored in `value` must be utf-8 encoded in order to be correctly converted to bytes, which can then by passed as an input to the `crypto.subtle.digest()` function.

Try changing:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(value);
```

to:

```
var buffer = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(value);
```

This creates a Uint8Array (as expected by `crypto.subtle.digest()`) consisting of the bytes resulting from utf-8 encoding the text string in 'value'.  This should solve the problem and produce the result that you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic function to generate a SHA-1 hex string digest for any input string:

```js
async function digest(message, algo = 'SHA-1') {
  return Array.from(
    new Uint8Array(
      await crypto.subtle.digest(algo, new TextEncoder().encode(message))
    ),
    (byte) => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')
  ).join('');
}
```

Comment: See the examples section of MDN for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest#examples