# Web scraping in Python - Arraybuffer to data readable

Tags: python, web-scraping, arraybuffer

I'm developing a web scraper for the Hoymiles monitoring system. One of the statistics I can get is historical data, but I get data in a strange format. After a lot of research and a search in the platform code, I found that in the post request made in addition to the headers and payload, they use a parameter that is the responseType: "arraybuffer". Hence, after more research, I found that arraybuffer is "a data type used to represent a generic, fixed-size binary data buffer".

My code is as follows:

```
def plants_data_historycal(self, authorization):

    payload = '''
        {
            "mode":3,
            "date":"2022-01-20"
        }
    '''

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'authorization': authorization,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Origin': 'https://global.hoymiles.com',
        'Referer': 'https://global.hoymiles.com/platform/login',
        'Cookie': cookie,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Mobile Safari/537.36'
    }

    response = self.session.post(self.url+'/pvm-data/api/0/statistics/count_station_eq', headers=headers, data=payload)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise RuntimeError("A requisição falhou: %s", response)

    print(response.text)
    data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    data = json.loads(data.text)

    return data
```

The response to my request looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20Y
pv_eqP��G�@H��[H�nH���H�0H��G���G�QH���G��H�JH�
�H`�H�1�H�ݗH@]sH��_H`j�H�!�H
```

The response.text before BeatifulSoup

```
\n\x011\n\x012\n\x013\n\x014\n\x015\n\x016\n\x017\n\x018\n\x019\n\x0210\n\x0211\n\x0212\n\x0213\n\x0214\n\x0215\n\x0216\n\x0217\n\x0218\n\x0219\n\x0220\n\x0221\n\x0222\n\x0223\x12e\n\x05pv_eq\x12\\\x00��G\x00�@H��[H\x00�nH���H�\x080H\x00��G���G�Q\x00H���G��\x02H�J\x03H�\r�H`�H�1�H�ݗH@]sH��_H`j�H�!�H���H`z�H I�H
```

To try to turn this string into something understandable, I tried to use the code available in the inspect option of the Hoymiles home page Chrome browser (https://global.hoymiles.com/platform/home). From there I found that they transformed the arraybuffer with the function

```
transformResponse: [
    function (e) {
            if ("string" == typeof e)
                   try {
                        e = JSON.parse(e);
                   } catch (e) {}
                        return e;
     },
],
```

But even with that, the arraybuffer comes empty. So I turned the response as arraybuffer into a Uint8Array, but I can't understand what the data means.

```
Uint8Array {
0: 123
1:34
10:34
11:49
12:48
13:48
14:34
15:44
16:34
17: 100
18:97
19: 116
2: 115
20: 97
21:34
22:58
23:34
24: 34
25:44
26: 34
27: 109
28: 101
29: 115
3: 116
30: 115
31: 97
32: 103
33: 101
34: 34
35: 58
36: 34
37: 116
38: 111
39: 107
4: 97
40: 101
41: 110
42: 32
43: 118
44: 101
45: 114
46: 105
47: 102
48: 121
49: 32
5: 116
50: 101
51: 114
52: 114
53: 111
54: 114
55: 46
56: 34
57: 125
6: 117
7: 115
8:34
9:58
}
```

Does anyone know how to turn this into readable or understandable data?

Comment: This is probably not the answer you're looking for. But I always found web scrapping in javascript to be a much more enjoyable experience using  the `puppeteer`  library.  In addition you can convert from arraybuffer to string in javascript quite easily (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers). If you know python learning javascript will be very easy.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I found that actually this is the python answer already in string and not in bytes. I tried to figure out how to turn the arraybuffer into something understandable in javascript, but I couldn't. I turned this arraybuffer into a Uint8Array, but I can't understand what the data means. I'll edit the question and add the array :)

Comment: You have a token verify error read my post below and accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I made a post with what I received with your code, in fact the response I am getting from the request is in json format

Answer (score 2):

So I don't know what data type you're expecting from that `Uint8Array`. But below are some insights that might help you answer your question. The Uint8Array typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers.
So theres ambiguity of what this is suppose to represent. It could be a String, a float, json, an int.

So the output you printed of the Uint8Array I'm assuming treats the keys as index positions in the array and the values are the values at that index in the array. **However index 50 is not a key in your output so that's confusing**

Anyways I made a Uint8Array with the values in the same order as your output below.

```js
// Same array you printed out
const lst = [ 123, 34, 115, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115,  34,  58,  34,  49,  48, 
 48, 34,  44,  34,  100,  97,  116,  97,  34,  58,34,  34,  44,  34,  109,  
 101,  115,  115,  97,  103,  101,  34,  58,  34,  116,  111,  107,  101, 
 110,  32,  118,  101,  114,  105,  102,  121,  32,  undefined,  114,  114,  
  111,  114,  46,  34 ]

// Make the Uint8Array
var data = new Uint8Array(lst);

// Print as String
let str = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
console.log(str); // output: eyJzdGF0dXMiOiIxMDAiLCJkYXRhIjoiIiwibWVzc2FnZSI6InRva2VuIHZlcmlmeSAAcnJvci4i


// Print as float 
const floatValue =new DataView(data.buffer).getFloat64(0);
console.log(floatValue) // output: 1.3718470458079746e+285

// Print as json
function printAsJson(arr) {
  let str = "";
  for (var i=0; i<arr.byteLength; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
  }

  var serializedData = JSON.stringify(str);
  let message = JSON.parse(serializedData);

  console.log(message)
}
printAsJson(data); // output: {"status":"100","data":"","message":"token verify rror."
```

**So to sum it up the json makes the most sense and it seems like you have a token verify error.**

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had a token verification error, since I was using an outdated version of the authorization token in the javascript code. So I compiled the code with the updated token and used your code.

Code

```
const lst = [10, 1, 49, 10, 1, 50, 10, 1, 51, 10, 1, 52, 10, 1, 53, 10, 1, 54, 10, 1, 55, 10, 1, 56, 10, 1, 57, 10, 2, 49, 48, 10, 2, 49, 49, 10, 2, 49 , 50, 10 , 2, 49 , 51, 10 , 2, 49 , 52 , 10 , 2 , 49 , 53 , 10 , 2 , 49 , 54 , 10 , 2 , 49 , 55 , 10 , 2 , 49 , 56 , 10 , 2 , 49 , 57 , 10 , 2 , 50 , 48 , 10 , 2 , 50 , 49 , 10 , 2 , 50 , 50 , 10 , 2 , 50 , 51 , 10 , 2 , 50 , 52 , 18 , 105 , 10 , 5 , 112 , 118 , 95 , 101 , 113 , 18 , 96 , 0 , 244 ,  214 ,  71 ,  0 ,  144 ,  64 ,  72 ,  128 ,  237 ,  91 ,  72 ,  0 ,  162 ,  110 ,  72 ,  128 ,  138 ,  130 ,  72 ,  128 ,  8 ,  48 ,  72 ,  0 ,  236 ,  252 ,  71 ,  128 ,  209 ,  205 ,  71 ,  192 ,  81 ,  0 ,  72 ,  128 ,  189 ,  253 ,  71 ,  128 ,  156 ,  2 ,  72 ,  192 ,  74 ,  3 ,  72 ,  128 ,  13 ,  128 ,  72 ,  96 ,  234 ,  150 ,  72 ,  192 ,  49 ,  161 ,  72 ,  224 ,  221 ,  151 ,  72 ,  64 ,  93 ,  115 ,  72 ,  192 ,  145 ,  95 ,  72 ,  96 ,  106 ,  129 ,  72 ,  160 ,  33 ,  164 ,  72 ,  160 ,  240 ,  143 ,  72 ,  96 ,  122 ,  147 ,  72 ,  32 ,  73 ,  158 ,  72 ,  160 ,  159 ,  139 ,  72]

var data = new Uint8Array(lst);

let str = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
console.log(str); 

const floatValue =new DataView(data.buffer).getFloat64(0);
console.log(floatValue) 

function printAsJson(arr) {
  let str = "";
  for (var i=0; i<arr.byteLength; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
  }

  var serializedData = JSON.stringify(str);
  let message = JSON.parse(serializedData);

  console.log(message)
}
printAsJson(data);
```

This was the result:

str

```
CgExCgEyCgEzCgE0CgE1CgE2CgE3CgE4CgE5CgIxMAoCMTEKAjEyCgIxMwoCMTQKAjE1CgIxNgoCMTcKAjE4CgIxOQoCMjAKAjIxCgIyMgoCMjMKAjI0EmkKBXB2X2VxEmAA9NZHAJBASIDtW0gAom5IgIqCSIAIMEgA7PxHgNHNR8BRAEiAvf1HgJwCSMBKA0iADYBIYOqWSMAxoUjg3ZdIQF1zSMCRX0hgaoFIoCGkSKDwj0hgepNIIEmeSKCfi0g=
```

floatValue

```
1.7470648220442632e-260
```

json

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24i
pv_eq`
```

Unfortunately, I still haven't gotten data that can be interpreted.