# How to know the text encoding scheme so that I can decode the bytes to a string

Tags: javascript, decode, subtlecrypto, textdecoder

I'm using Chrome Browser's `crypto.SubCrypto` [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto). I generate a PSA-PSS key in it and want to export the key:

```
let key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {
    name: "RSA-PSS",
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
    hash: "SHA-256",
  },
  true, 
  ["sign", "verify"] 
);

let exported_key = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("spki", key.publicKey);

let export_key_buffer = new Uint8Array(exported_key); // convert the key from an ArrayBuffer to a TypedArray

// Convert export_key_buffer into a string
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
let string_key = decoder.decode(export_key_buffer)
console.log(string_key). // unreadable text
```

Basically, I generate a key with [`generateKey()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902334/13030001) and then export it with [`exportKey()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902334/13030001). The `exportKey` returns an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902334/13030001) and I want to turn that into a string, so I follow an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902334/13030001), which uses [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder). But the `TextDecoder` decodes the `exported_key_buffer` into unreadable string:

```
0�"0
    *�H��
�0�
��<FY�d!��Ø+�XM]�A�/�ݔM�pRZ���[��&5�-���w]@��^�e
�����~����eq�Y^�
��EѮf�8v��z{(���GF
�x�;�����N?eP�Xe���D�C ��C4+��}?�|/Oj:u�q�j�
�q�-z�����r+�+˫��x3T�V������oQTS��EA?��yY�J��
�M��8o�L��MND�u��2�ks�=�{G��c�6e��]8
```

I think this is because the bytes are not `uft8` encoded (the default decoding scheme of `TextDecoder` is utf8)? How can I find out the right decoding scheme?

I am not familiar with text encoding/decoding and I appreciate your help.

Comment: you have to hope that there is some "byte order mark" in front of the text (shortened as "BOM"), It's explained at https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM

Comment: Oh, I just read half of the question obviously. You probably can't use a TextDecoder for this, as this is not text but a crypto key. You could try to do a base64 encoding, if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cyberbrain.

Like what he said the `exported_key` is not a text but a binary array. So if I want to convert it to text, I could use base64 encoding:

```
function arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}

let base64key = arrayBufferToBase64(exported_key)
```

Then you have an ASCII string like this

```
IIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsep59DiyKMh3v1INHvBtoIrZgv9Vw3bvc6Ttr0DMAChSpmPdnssUsbs3mESKCDY ...
```