# How to hash a string using Deno

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

Given the string `hello world` how do I get the string `b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9` as provided by the "SHA256 Online" generator found here: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html.

I'm looking to use Deno for this. There aren't many good resources online about how to do this so I wanted to create a single reference that was easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

Deno uses the [web crypto api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API), so how you'd achieve this in the browser is the same as with Deno. This answer was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75023280/340688).

```js
async function hash(message) {
  const data = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data)
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer))
  const hashHex = hashArray.map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')
  return hashHex
}

hash('hello world').then(console.log)
```