# Reading PDF file using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, cordova

I'm currently developing an application that would `Copy/Transfer a sentence/paragraph from a PDF file to my program`. I'm using Javascript to develop my program but I have not found any idea how to read a PDF file.

I want to know how to Copy/Transfer a sentence/paragraph from a PDF file to my program?

Thanks.

Comment: What about https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 17):

I know that the question is old, but if you find PDF.js too complex for the job, `npm install` [pdfreader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfreader). (I wrote that module)

It would take 5 lines of code to extract text from your PDF file:

```
var PdfReader = require("pdfreader").PdfReader;
new PdfReader().parseFileItems("sample.pdf", function(err, item){
  if (item && item.text)
    console.log(item.text);
});
```

Comment: 'It does not work from a web browser.' Guessing this means I couldn't use browserify with it?

Comment: I don't know, @static_null. Let us know how it goes if you give it a try!

Comment: @AdrienJoly hi do you know where/how I can get the compiled version of pdfreader module? I'm hoping to get one .js file so I could use it as a library.

Thank you!

Comment: @Daj I am not distributing any bundled version of pdfreader. Feel free to use the bundler of your choice (e.g. webpack or other) to achieve that.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), it's a commonly used JavaScript library that contains a lot of methods for PDF manipulation.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554280/extract-text-from-pdf-in-javascript#answer-20522307) to see a demonstration of how to extract text using pdf.js.