# If String starts with a number check the length of the string

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i want to use javascript in a .pdf file.
I want to check if a string starts with "1" or with a letter.

If the string starts with "1" i want to check the length of the string. 
If the string is 18 chars long, then i want to call my own created function. 
If the String is shorter than 18 chars i want to display a message.

If the string starts with a letter, i want to check the length of the string.
If the string is 11 chars long, then i want to call my own created function. 
If the String is shorter than 11 chars i want to display a message.

But how i can do this?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066118/reading-pdf-file-using-javascript) to your first problem. Good luck!

Comment: Do you know how to read pdf and process it with javascript. because string length validation is simple , but i dont think that you only need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var string = "Your String";
if(string[0] === '1'){
    if(string.length >= 18 )
        callYourFunction();
    else
        alert("Your Message");
}
else if(isNaN(string[0])){
    if(string.length >= 11 )
        callYourFunction();
    else
        alert("Your Message");
}
```

Here, string.length returns the length of the string as integer. 
isNaN() checks whether the parameter is not a number. It returns false if the parameter is a number.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. But i have to use app.alert({cMsg:'Your Message', cTitle:'Your Message'});

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to this:

```
if (typeof variableName == 'string' || variableName instanceof String){
   if(variableName[0] == '1'){
     if(variableName.length == 18){
       //call your method
       console.log("It's 18th character long");
     } else if(variableName.length == 11){
       //call another method
       console.log("It's 11th character long");
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first character like so - `string[0]`.
Strings behave like arrays in this way.
You can test the length of a string like so - `string.length`

```
var string1 = "1dgfe";

if (string1[0] == 1 && string1.length > 18){
    yourfunction();
} else if (string1[0] == 1 && string1.length < 18){
    console.log('your message');
}
```