# How to use URL.createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, base64, fetch

My aim is to have a form that submits a URL to an endpoint that returns a base64 encoding of a PDF that is shown on screen **without** a `window.open` popup.

Example output I want: https://s.natalian.org/2017-04-04/index.html
[image: Desired output, a Web page with an embedded PDF]

I'm confused how to use the resulting **objectURL** to show the **data:application/pdf;base64** response.

With https://s.natalian.org/2017-04-04/ObjectURL.html I assume I am not decoding the base64 response properly? I don't know how to get it to render as a PDF like the output I want above.

Comment: `blob ?` - well, what does the server return? if it's a blob, return `response.blob()` to the next `.then` (that you don't yet have) in the chain

Comment: server returns base64

Comment: so what do you need? a blob? a dataURI? something else? You don't have any code to show the result "on the screen", so, how are you going to do that?

Comment: I could use window.open, but I don't want to use that since it results in a popup in Chrome and doesn't work at all in Safari.

Comment: two other options are an `<iframe>`, or an `<object>`

Comment: Can't get object to work https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/h0u4vLn3/7/

Comment: URL at `fetch()` at jsfiddle responds with `502` error

Comment: Is an authentication token required at server?

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/h0u4vLn3/11/

Comment: _"I'm confused how to use the resulting objectURL to show the data:application/pdf;base64 response."_ Note, `URL.createObjectURL()` returns a `Blob URL`, not a `data URI`.

Comment: So how do I make it work?

Comment: If you are making require with required authentication, you can use approach at [Displaying pdf from arraybuffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106584/displaying-pdf-from-arraybuffer/). If response is a `data URI`, you can use `.text()` and set text response at `.then()` directly at `iframe` `src`

Comment: Well I still struggle with my own question but you may take a look at below if  any of them helps; a [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066118/reading-pdf-file-using-javascript) and an [Example](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001948.html)

Comment: So, `response.blob()` returns a Blob which is UA-local URL. You are trying to build a data URI, for which you need the contents of the response. So with `response.text()` your approach should work, but because of the lack of CORS header, I can’t fix that in the Fiddle.

If you want to work with Blob(), your server should return a binary PDF, not the base64 of a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

How do you display a PDF now? It seems you'd need something like https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js to do this without relying on plugins. If you need a URL, getting a blob URL from a `Blob` object seems the most straightforward.

Comment: Maybe this a fiddle problem, but I don't see how to access the resulting URL from https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/h0u4vLn3/8/ ... 'blob:https://fiddle.jshell.net/8d385365-4471-4c92-af08-59dff4454142' doesn't work.

Comment: You should be able to put it in an `<a>` or some such and click that.

Answer (score 0):

As Surma points out in the comments: "If you want to work with Blob(), your server should return a binary PDF", and the problem with my endpoint was that it was returning a base64 encoded response.

I have since worked out how to make serverless respond in binary and posted the code here: https://github.com/calvintychan/serverless-html-pdf/pull/2