# PDFJS: Invalid PDF structure

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am attempting to extract plain text out of a pdf document using `pdf.js` and for some reason am unable to get past the `Invalid PDF structure` error.

My code as such:

```
const pdfjslib = require('pdfjs-dist');

const pdfPath = 'https://www.corenet.gov.sg/media/2268607/dc19-07.pdf'

var loadingTask = pdfjslib.getDocument(pdfPath);
loadingTask.promise.then(async (doc) => {
    console.log(doc);
    return null
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
});
```

I have tried other pdf documents coming from the same domain but all throws the same error:

```
...
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "34" in hex string
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "104" in hex string
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
{ Error
    at InvalidPDFExceptionClosure (.../pdf_test/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:658:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...pdf_test/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:661:2)
    at __w_pdfjs_require__ (.../pdf_test/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:52:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (...pdf_test/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:129:23)
    at __w_pdfjs_require__ (.../pdf_test/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:52:30)
    at pdfjsVersion (...pdf_test/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:116:18)
    at .../pdf_test/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:119:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (.../pdf_test/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:25:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../pdf_test/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:32:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
  name: 'InvalidPDFException',
  message: 'Invalid PDF structure' }
```

Other pdfs from other domains seem to work. Note that downloading the pdf from the above domain works well, and can be viewed on Chrome browser. I doubt that the pdf document is corrupted. I am not implementing any front end code as the intention of the above code is host it on cloud.

Comment: This answer has an alternative script for extracting data you could try - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29032269/2570277

Comment: Maybe the website you are downloading the PDF from checks the request headers. Can you try downloading the PDF with chrome and load it locally?

Comment: @Cr4xy yes, I could download the PDF and load it locally. It loads and extract the plain text correctly. If request header is the "issue", any idea how do I go around it without downloading the pdf?

Comment: You could try to copy all the headers you can find with chrome dev tools, and add them to getDocument like [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3852#issuecomment-373169304)

Comment: @Cr4xy I have attempted to copy all headers and add them to `httpHeaders`. However, the crucial header to add to make it work seems to be the `cookies` header. Is this expected?

Comment: "I doubt that the pdf document is corrupted" _don't guess, verify_. So, step 1: grab Adobe Acrobat, the free version, and try to open those PDFs. Then [edit] your post so that it mentions whether, according to the most authoritative PDF reader that exists, these PDF files are broken or not. Because if Acrobat doesn't like them, this isn't a problem with pdfjs in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

Browser console log errors did not help me to fix it.

I run a PHP app (Moodle) and I went to the PHP error log and saw some variables expected to be replaced within the html source body of my certificate to be generated.

Check your backend app for error logs and the html source body provided to PDF.js for missing and undefined variables.

Try starting over the html body provided to PDF.js from scratch will help debugging the source of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this type of poor file structure before. whilst most readers will initially accept them as full of deletions they cause later problems.

The info metadata  has been culled along with many other redactions but the index has not been rebuilt cleanly.
These files may cause distorted behaviours such as missing annotation and other processing oddities.

One important indexed entry is declared as active (the one for pages) then later declared as deleted, so the number of pages is technically invalidated. However as commented by @mkl the combined methods are valid, and will usually be passed as acceptable according to the accesability standards EXCEPT the title had been removed along with the metadata.
Once the "Title" is added as part of the manual checks it is fully up to scratch, but will naturally remove redundant entries and add others so file size is reduced.

```
endobj
startxref
27552
%%EOF

Summary
The checker found no problems in this document.

Needs manual check: 0
Passed manually: 2
Failed manually: 0
Skipped: 1
Passed: 29
Failed: 0
```

Looking at the source file position 125 is the list of pages.

`2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Count 2/Kids[ 3 0 R 17 0 R] >> endobj`

[image]

However then the whole table is encoded yet again.

```
trailer
<</Size 156/Root 1 0 R/Info 148 0 R/ID[<F8D1F9DF5B960D47837AA3719AED9B81><F8D1F9DF5B960D47837AA3719AED9B81>] >>
startxref
27702
%%EOF
xref
0 0
trailer
<</Size 156/Root 1 0 R/Info 148 0 R/ID[<F8D1F9DF5B960D47837AA3719AED9B81><F8D1F9DF5B960D47837AA3719AED9B81>] /Prev 27702/XRefStm 27153>>
startxref
30982
%%EOF
```

The best thing to do is run the file through any cleaning process to rationalise the working index even if that means a percentage increase in file size.

[image]

Beware avoid using Ghostscript to rebuild the file (without any redundant objects) it will reduce the count drastically from 156 down to 33. Thus the cleaned optimised file is much smaller, but has lost all accessibility data.

Avoid basic optimisation `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -oTestIt.pdf dc19-07.pdf`

```
0000012448 00000 n 
0000017006 00000 n 
0000020240 00000 n 
0000007646 00000 n 
0000019954 00000 n 
0000022761 00000 n 
trailer
<< /Size 33 /Root 1 0 R /Info 2 0 R
/ID [<3488BED994E047F0C0FAB9AB78CA5FF8><3488BED994E047F0C0FAB9AB78CA5FF8>]
>>
startxref
24137
%%EOF
```

Mutool cleaning is more likely to keep desired source  data.
`mutool clean -m -s -f -i -gggg dc19-07.pdf clean-DC19-07.pdf`

Comment: Hhmmm, the structure parts you show look like what one regularly sees in PDFs created by MS Word, hybrid cross references done in a specific way. They usually are completely valid, so properly implemented tools should not run into problems with them. In particular the first number in an **f** xref entry has a different meaning than the first entry in an **n** xref entry, so object 2 is **not** *declared deleted* by the excerpts above. (Currently I'm only on a smart phone; when I'm back at my laptop I'll also take a look at that file to check whether there are actually invalid aspects in it.)