# Extract text from pdf with PDFJS (2018)

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I discovered that earlier versions of code that are used to extract texts using PDFJS no longer work with the recent version of PDFJS. Here are some previous versions

[Extract text from pdf file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424639/extract-text-from-pdf-file-using-javascript)

[how to correctly extract text from a pdf using pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635979/how-to-correctly-extract-text-from-a-pdf-using-pdf-js)

[extract text from pdf in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554280/extract-text-from-pdf-in-javascript)
.

Does anyone have a current code that works?

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over getTextContent()s return value.

```
pdfDoc.getPage(1).then((p) => {
p.getTextContent().then((textContent) => {
// Iterate here
});
});
```

Comment: Not unless you have a more specific thing you'd like to know

Comment: Actually I have already solve this problem. I upload the file then I can read the file with javascript but I would like to read it directly from an input type file. Do you know how to read the pdf from an input type file?