# Is it possible to extract the text selected by the user in a pdf?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554280/extract-text-from-pdf-in-javascript) that explains how to extract the text from a pdf in javascript, but I would like to know if it's possible to extract only the text selected by the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can not.

The PDF, unless it's being rendered by a javascript renderer (as-in, pdf.js), can not be accessed at all by the browser's javascript.

This is because it's being rendered by a browser plugin that the javascript is intentionally not allowed to access.

Your post is tagged with "google-chrome-extension" and "google-chrome" but your question does not mention these. You might not be asking a specific enough question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should precise it's for a chrome extension, so maybe it's possible with the chrome api?