# on submitting form pdf should be uploaded and saved in my local disk

Tags: javascript, file-upload

when i select a pdf file from my pc and click on submit button. Default embeded pdf should be replaced by new pdf that i uploaded. By using only javascript

```
<form action="" id="myform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                <input type="file" name="uploadfile" placeholder="Upload file" id="">

                <button id="submitfile" class="filesubmitbutton">Submit</button>
            </form>

                <embed id="myEmbed" src="../NISHANTKUMAR.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px">
```

can uderstand how to do it i tried to change src of embed using javascript But i cant get actual path of file in input

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, it is not possible to access the real file path programmatically on the user machine. You only have two options

- Upload the pdf file to your server and update the embed src accordingly
- Read the pdf content (yes, while you cannot know the file path, you can read the file content) and render it using an external JS PDF viewer, (e.g. [how to open a local PDF in PDFJS using file input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048395/how-to-open-a-local-pdf-in-pdfjs-using-file-input))