# Why PDF preview is not working with pdfjs in ionic7

Tags: javascript, pdf, ionic-framework

Hi pdfjs document preview works fine in web app but does not work on Android mobile phone

**Question :**  Preview is not working either with external url and with input on android phone(shows blank) but works on web app any possible reason for this?

```js
/*Offical release of the pdfjs worker*/
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.5.207/pdf.worker.js';
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function() {
    var typedarray = new Uint8Array(this.result);
    console.log(typedarray);
    const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedarray);
    loadingTask.promise.then(pdf => {
      // The document is loaded here...
      //This below is just for demonstration purposes showing that it works with the moderen api
      pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
        console.log('Page loaded');

        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport({
          scale: scale
        });

        var canvas = document.getElementById('pdfCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        renderTask.promise.then(function() {
          console.log('Page rendered');
        });

      });
      //end of example code
    });

  }
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
  <!-- The offical release-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.5.207/pdf.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <h2>Rendered pdf:</h2>
    <canvas id="pdfCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

  </body>

</html>
```

I have followed this example:  [how to open a local PDF in PDFJS using file input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048395/how-to-open-a-local-pdf-in-pdfjs-using-file-input)