# Extracting Tables from PDF files in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way for extracting Tables which are embedded in PDF documents?

I am not interested solutions which work only for JRuby, or which make use of third-party APIs or web-sites.

Can you share some Ruby code on how to extract the table(s)?
Which gems are best suited for the job?

I'm sure someone has had the same problem before :)
I appreciate your help!

Comment: Extracting data organized in structured layouts from PDF files is much harder than you might anticipate and it is unlikely that you will be able to get a very reliable solution that works on arbitrary PDF files.

Comment: I have PDF files which get generated by one company, so I was hoping that they don't change their PDF generation tool, and always use the same format

Comment: What are you trying to do with the tables? Do you want them in html format? text format?

Comment: I want to extract the text from the tables and get the data as strings for each column/row

Comment: Both @ZachTuttle's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41963389/2628223) and [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42017186/2628223) would solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract data from a pdf with [poppler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software)). Depending on your exact requirements, this may be sufficient.

```
def extract_to_text(pdf_path)
  command = ['pdftotext', Shellwords.escape(pdf_path)].join(' ')
  `#{command}`
end

def extract_to_html(pdf_path)
  command = ['pdftohtml', Shellwords.escape(pdf_path)].join(' ')
  `#{command}`
end
```

These commands will extract the pdfs to an html file and text file, respectively, saved at the same location where your pdf was.

You can install poppler on a mac with homebrew:

```
brew install poppler
```

Comment: this might be an interesting link https://github.com/ashima/pdf-table-extract to do the actual table extraction

Comment: @Tilo yes that looks promising. It's in Python but you could mimic the logic.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at this answer ([How to convert PDF to Excel or CSV in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183738/how-to-convert-pdf-to-excel-or-csv-in-rails-4?answertab=active#tab-top)). It solves the same problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I can not use a third-party API / site  to process the PDFs, because they contain confidential data

Comment: @Tilo: AFAIK, this gem extracts the table locally, without needing any third-party to process the PDF. Sure, you need to trust the code, but you can audit it before launching it.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this gem I think it's what your looking for: [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) gem

Comment: this looks good, but I don't see any special handling of tables

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem called [Iguvium](https://github.com/adworse/iguvium) that does exactly this. Here is an example

```
pages = Iguvium.read('filename.pdf')
tables = pages.first.extract_tables!
csv = tables.first.to_a.map(&:to_csv).join
```