# How to make web apps to read and analyze pdf file?

Tags: pdf

I have a project from my lecture to create a web apps to read and analyze a pdf file based on keywords. What kind of programming language that I can use?

Example : I need to find or check some keywords or data on the pdf file. If the keyword or data is exist and available, the result is true.

Answer (score 0):

I usually work in javascript so could answer you in that, I had a great help from the below conversation, it might be a good help for you too.

[extract text from pdf in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554280/extract-text-from-pdf-in-javascript)