# How do I retrieve text from user selection in pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

This question is specific to pdf.js, a javascript based pdf renderer. I'm building a custom version where I need to extract the text that I select inside the pdf.

There are other posts where you can fetch the text from one page or the whole pdf document such as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554280/extract-text-from-pdf-in-javascript) , but I'm looking to grab a specific text that the user selects and perhaps alert it or print it in the console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) method. This method returns a specific Selection object with the range of the selected text on the web page.

Here is how you can use `getSelection()` together with **[pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)**:

```
function getHightlightCoords() {
var pageIndex = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber - 1; 
var page = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.getPageView(pageIndex);
var pageRect = page.canvas.getClientRects()[0];
var selectionRects = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects();
var viewport = page.viewport;
var selected = selectionRects.map(function (r) {
  return viewport.convertToPdfPoint(r.left - pageRect.x, r.top - pageRect.y).concat(
     viewport.convertToPdfPoint(r.right - pageRect.x, r.bottom - pageRect.y)); 
});
return {page: pageIndex, coords: selected};
}


function showHighlight(selected) {
var pageIndex = selected.page; 
var page = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.getPageView(pageIndex);
var pageElement = page.canvas.parentElement;
var viewport = page.viewport;
selected.coords.forEach(function (rect) {
  var bounds = viewport.convertToViewportRectangle(rect);
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; background-color: pink;' + 
    'left:' + Math.min(bounds[0], bounds[2]) + 'px; top:' + Math.min(bounds[1], bounds[3]) + 'px;' +
    'width:' + Math.abs(bounds[0] - bounds[2]) + 'px; height:' + Math.abs(bounds[1] - bounds[3]) + 'px;');
  pageElement.appendChild(el);
});
}
```

Comment: I achieved what I wanted thanks to your suggestion. The solution provided achieves way more than what I needed, but pretty interesting though. I just needed window.getSelection().toString() to get the text inside, and coupled it with an event handler. :)

Comment: On another note, in the solution you provided, the **.map()** inside **getHighlightCoords()** does not seem to work, as selectionRects i.e. **"window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects();"** returns an object of objects rather than an array of objects, so you would need to convert it to an array similar to this : **"var selectionRectsList = Object.values(selectionRects);"**

Comment: @SrikarReddy can you please confirm how you accomplished it

Comment: @SrikarReddy window.getSelection().toString() doesn't give me the correct selection but all the content of the div. Could you have an hint to get the specific text selected ?

Comment: doesnt work in pdf.js 2.12. all coordinates are NaN

Answer (score 6):

pdf.js has a file viewer.html inside the directory web.

you have to do the following two steps in viwer.html

1. Add Event Listener onselectionchange.
2. Define the event handling function onselectionchange().

```
<script>

  // addEventListener version
  document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
    console.log(document.getSelection());
  });

  // onselectionchange version
  document.onselectionchange = () => {
    var text = getSelectedText();

    if(text)
    {
      alert(text); 

    }
  };

  function getSelectedText() {
     if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
     } 
     else if (document.selection) {
         return document.selection.createRange().text;
     }
     return '';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In reply to chitgoks message (*doesnt work in pdf.js 2.12*)

I made a small adaption to semanser code and testet it in Chrome 97 and PDF.js: 2.13.99

```
function getHightlightCoords() {
var pageIndex = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber - 1; 
var page = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.getPageView(pageIndex);
var pageRect = page.canvas.getClientRects()[0];
var selectionRects = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects();
var viewport = page.viewport;
var r = selectionRects[0];
var selected = viewport.convertToPdfPoint(r.left - pageRect.x, r.top - pageRect.y).concat(
     viewport.convertToPdfPoint(r.right - pageRect.x, r.bottom - pageRect.y)); 
return {page: pageIndex, coords: selected};
}



// addEventListener version
  document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
    console.log(getHightlightCoords());
  });
```

It works for me!

Comment: This function with showHighlights will result in the div layer left, top, width, and height to also be NaN? Because of this bounds = viewport.convertToViewportRectangle(rect) results in bounds having [NaN,NaN, NaN, NaN]. While i have done this use case, my problem is with text selection sensitivity. pdf.js has enable_enhanced option for textLayerMode but the retrieved client recs are wrong but the text selection sensitivity works as expected