# JavaScript to get the coordinates of a specific string within an PDF file

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

Is there a JavaScript solution allowing me to get the x- and y-coordinates as well as the width and the height of a specific string within a PDF file? PDF.JS can extract text chunks out of a PDF file and give the x- and y-coordinates as well as the width and the height of those chunks. But I have no influence on how these text chunks are grouped together (from single characters to larger pieces of several words) and I don't know how to address the coordinates of parts of such a chunk.

This means that if a PDF file contains "Hello world!", I would like to be able to know the x-coordinate of where "Hello" ends or where "world" starts.

Is there any way more comfortable than trying to calculate this via the width of the single characters of the given font? In Java, PDFBox allows to do so (see [How to search some specific string or a word and there coordinates from a pdf document in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937774/how-to-search-some-specific-string-or-a-word-and-there-coordinates-from-a-pdf-do)), but I haven't found anything comparable in JavaScript.

The reason I'm trying to do this is that I want to search for a specific text in the PDF file and find out its coordinates in order to do something with it, like drawing a rectangle around it to highlight it. Any advice on how to achieve this would be very welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Try using https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#online-demo

Answer (score 1):

one way is you can use window.getSelection() to get the co-ordinates of the text selected and using toString() to convert it to the text format.

[ng2-pdf-viewer: get coordinates of highlighted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379410/ng2-pdf-viewer-get-coordinates-of-highlighted-text).

Please feel free to comment, as this is my first post.